# Finding All Combinations (Cartesian product) of JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can I produce all of the combinations of the values in N number of JavaScript arrays of variable lengths?

Let's say I have N number of JavaScript arrays, e.g.

```
var first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var second = ['e'];
var third =  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
```

(Three arrays in this example, but its N number of arrays for the problem.)

And I want to output all the combinations of their values, to produce

```
aef
aeg
aeh
aei
aej
bef
beg
....
dej
```

---

EDIT: Here's the version I got working, using ffriend's accepted answer as the basis.

```
var allArrays = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']];

 function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } 
  else if (arr.length ===1){
    return arr[0];
  }
  else {
    var result = [];
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));  // recur with the rest of array
    for (var c in allCasesOfRest) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        result.push(arr[0][i] + allCasesOfRest[c]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

}
var results = allPossibleCases(allArrays);
 //outputs ["acd", "bcd", "azd", "bzd", "ace", "bce", "aze", "bze", "acf", "bcf", "azf", "bzf"]
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is not permutations, see [permutations definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) from Wikipedia.

But you can achieve this with **recursion**:

```js
var allArrays = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c'],
  ['d', 'e', 'f']
]

function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); // recur with the rest of array
    for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[0][j] + allCasesOfRest[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

}

console.log(allPossibleCases(allArrays))
```

You can also make it with loops, but it will be a bit tricky and will require implementing your own analogue of stack.

Answer (score 41):

I suggest a simple recursive [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) as follows:

```js
// Generate cartesian product of given iterables:
function* cartesian(head, ...tail) {
  let remainder = tail.length ? cartesian(...tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
}

// Example:
const first  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const second = ['e'];
const third  = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

console.log(...cartesian(first, second, third));
```

Comment: This is indeed beautiful. For those of you who want to use an unknown number of inputs and store the result in an array, you can do: const product = [...cartesian.apply(this, [first, second, third, fourth, etc])];

Comment: @Andrew why `.apply` and not splat the arguments to cartesian? `const product = [...cartesian(...unknownNumberOfInputs)];`

Comment: Beautiful. How to modify to satisfy [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178060/what-is-the-method-in-javascript-to-solve-below-problem) where the permutations of single, double etc strings are required

Answer (score 25):

You don't need recursion, or heavily nested loops, or even to generate/store the whole array of permutations in memory.

Since the number of permutations is the product of the lengths of each of the arrays (call this `numPerms`), you can create a function `getPermutation(n)` that returns a unique permutation between index `0` and `numPerms - 1` by calculating the indices it needs to retrieve its characters from, based on `n`.

How is this done? If you think of creating permutations on arrays each containing: [0, 1, 2, ... 9] it's very simple... the 245th permutation (n=245) is "245", rather intuitively, or:

```
arrayHundreds[Math.floor(n / 100) % 10]
+ arrayTens[Math.floor(n / 10) % 10]
+ arrayOnes[Math.floor(n / 1) % 10]
```

The complication in your problem is that array sizes differ. We can work around this by replacing the `n/100`, `n/10`, etc... with other divisors. We can easily pre-calculate an array of divisors for this purpose. In the above example, the divisor of 100 was equal to `arrayTens.length * arrayOnes.length`. Therefore we can calculate the divisor for a given array to be the product of the lengths of the remaining arrays. The very last array always has a divisor of 1. Also, instead of modding by 10, we mod by the length of the current array.

Example code is below:

```
var allArrays = [first, second, third, ...];

// Pre-calculate divisors
var divisors = [];
for (var i = allArrays.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   divisors[i] = divisors[i + 1] ? divisors[i + 1] * allArrays[i + 1].length : 1;
}

function getPermutation(n) {
   var result = "", curArray;

   for (var i = 0; i < allArrays.length; i++) {
      curArray = allArrays[i];
      result += curArray[Math.floor(n / divisors[i]) % curArray.length];
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Very nice. There is a typo here though, `results` should show `result` -- I notice you loop backwards for calculating the divisors, I assume the position of the divisor in the array is important?

Comment: @Gary, thanks for picking that up. The order of the divisors matters because the first one depends on the second, the second depends on the third, etc... So by looping backwards I can build this up more easily.

Comment: @Box9: Does this function works with 1 array? Isn't it (n*n) - (n-1)?

Comment: @epitaph, it should still work with 1 array. `divisors` will only have one element: `[1]`, and so it will always divide by 1, and mod by the array length - in effect, doing nothing.

Comment: If it works on 1 array and the result (n*n)-(n-1) can I use it to make a cost matrix? For example for the travelsalesman problem?

Comment: @epitaph, really not sure what you mean. Are you talking about generating all permutations of the elements in a single array? That is different to what this question is asking (and hence the answer).

Comment: Yes, but the OP has asked this, too.

Comment: It's not permutations, as stated above, it's combinations. Shouldn't you update your answer and replace permutation with combination? The algorithm itself is great.

Comment: I thank you so very much for this. Had to adjust it a bit for my needs, but very good base.

Answer (score 17):

Provided answers looks too difficult for me. So my solution is:

```js
var allArrays = new Array(['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']);

function getPermutation(array, prefix) {
  prefix = prefix || '';
  if (!array.length) {
    return prefix;
  }

  var result = array[0].reduce(function(result, value) {
    return result.concat(getPermutation(array.slice(1), prefix + value));
  }, []);
  return result;
}

console.log(getPermutation(allArrays));
```

Comment: Hi. How can this be modified to return an array of arrays instead of array of strings? So instead of ["acd","ace","acf" ...] to return [["a","c",d"], ["a","c","e"] ....]

Answer (score 9):

You could take a single line approach by generating a cartesian product.

```
result = items.reduce(
    (a, b) => a.reduce(
        (r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))),
        []
    )
);
```

```js
var items = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']],
    result = items.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));
 
console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How to use to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178060/what-is-the-method-in-javascript-to-solve-below-problem)

Answer (score 7):

Copy of le_m's Answer to take Array of Arrays directly:

```
function *combinations(arrOfArr) {
  let [head, ...tail] = arrOfArr
  let remainder = tail.length ? combinations(tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
}
```

Hope it saves someone's time.

Comment: You could have used le_m's as such: `cartesian(...arrOfArr)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a typical backtracking:

```
function cartesianProductConcatenate(arr) {
  var data = new Array(arr.length);
  return (function* recursive(pos) {
    if(pos === arr.length) yield data.join('');
    else for(var i=0; i<arr[pos].length; ++i) {
      data[pos] = arr[pos][i];
      yield* recursive(pos+1);
    }
  })(0);
}
```

I used generator functions to avoid allocating all the results simultaneously, but if you want you can

```
[...cartesianProductConcatenate([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']])];
// ["acd","ace","acf","azd","aze","azf","bcd","bce","bcf","bzd","bze","bzf"]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Easiest way to find the Combinations**

```js
const arr1= [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
const arr2= [ '1', '2', '3' ];
const arr3= [ 'x', 'y', ];

const all = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

const output = all.reduce((acc, cu) => { 
    let ret = [];
      acc.map(obj => {
        cu.map(obj_1 => {
          ret.push(obj + '-' + obj_1) 
        });
      });
      return ret;
   })

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This fails on an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a flow-compatible function that can handle two dimensional arrays with any item type, you can use the function below.

```
const getUniqueCombinations = <T>(items : Array<Array<T>>, prepend : Array<T> = []) : Array<Array<T>> => {
    if(!items || items.length === 0) return [prepend];

    let out = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++){
        out = [...out, ...getUniqueCombinations(items.slice(1), [...prepend, items[0][i]])];
    }

    return out;
}
```

A visualisation of the operation:

**in:**

```
[
    [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3],
    [Obj4, Obj5],
    [Obj6, Obj7]
]
```

**out:**

```
[
    [Obj1, Obj4, Obj6 ],
    [Obj1, Obj4, Obj7 ],
    [Obj1, Obj5, Obj6 ],
    [Obj1, Obj5, Obj7 ],
    [Obj2, Obj4, Obj6 ],
    [Obj2, Obj4, Obj7 ],
    [Obj2, Obj5, Obj6 ],
    [Obj2, Obj5, Obj7 ],
    [Obj3, Obj4, Obj6 ],
    [Obj3, Obj4, Obj7 ],
    [Obj3, Obj5, Obj6 ],
    [Obj3, Obj5, Obj7 ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a 2D array and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it. Then use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to create combinations of strings in the accumulator array and the current array being iterated and concatenate them.

```js
const data = [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'] ]

const output = data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.flatMap(c => cur.map(n => c + n)) )

console.log(output)
```

Comment: How can you obtain the list in ARRAY format and not strings? So instead of "abc" to have it return as array ["a","b","c"]

Comment: @BlasterGod that's a Cartesian product. I have answered that with a similar approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597533/3082296

Answer (score 2):

**2021 version of David Tang's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331713/12496886)**
Also inspired with Neil Mountford's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301002/12496886)

```js
const getAllCombinations = (arraysToCombine) => {
  const divisors = [];
  let permsCount = 1;
  for (let i = arraysToCombine.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      divisors[i] = divisors[i + 1] ? divisors[i + 1] * arraysToCombine[i + 1].length : 1;
      permsCount *= (arraysToCombine[i].length || 1);
  }

  const getCombination = (n, arrays, divisors) => arrays.reduce((acc, arr, i) => {
      acc.push(arr[Math.floor(n / divisors[i]) % arr.length]);
      return acc;
  }, []);

  const combinations = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < permsCount; i++) {
      combinations.push(getCombination(i, arraysToCombine, divisors));
  }
  return combinations;
};

console.log(getAllCombinations([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'z'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]));
```

Benchmarks: https://jsbench.me/gdkmxhm36d/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version adapted from the above couple of answers, that produces the results in the order specified in the OP, and returns strings instead of arrays:

```
function *cartesianProduct(...arrays) {
  if (!arrays.length) yield [];
  else {
    const [tail, ...head] = arrays.reverse();
    const beginning = cartesianProduct(...head.reverse());
    for (let b of beginning) for (let t of tail) yield b + t;
  }
}

const first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const second = ['e'];
const third =  ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
console.log([...cartesianProduct(first, second, third)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function too:

```
const result = (arrayOfArrays) => arrayOfArrays.reduce((t, i) => { let ac = []; for (const ti of t) { for (const ii of i) { ac.push(ti + '/' + ii) } } return ac })

result([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']])
// which will output [ 'a/e/f', 'a/e/g', 'a/e/h','a/e/i','a/e/j','b/e/f','b/e/g','b/e/h','b/e/i','b/e/j','c/e/f','c/e/g','c/e/h','c/e/i','c/e/j','d/e/f','d/e/g','d/e/h','d/e/i','d/e/j']
```

Of course you can remove the  `+ '/'` in `ac.push(ti + '/' + ii)`  to eliminate the slash from the final result. And you can replace those `for (... of ...)` with forEach functions (plus respective semicolon before `return ac`), whatever of those you are more comfortable with.

Comment: You could also minify one of the other answers :) The goal is not to have it on one line. Readable code is a goal in itself.

Answer (score 0):

An array approach without recursion:

```
const combinations = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8']];
let outputCombinations = combinations[0]

combinations.slice(1).forEach(row => {
  outputCombinations = outputCombinations.reduce((acc, existing) =>
    acc.concat(row.map(item => existing + item))
  , []);
});

console.log(outputCombinations);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [`a`, `b`, `c`];
let arr2 = [`p`, `q`, `r`];
let arr3 = [`x`, `y`, `z`];
let result = [];

arr1.forEach(e1 => {
    arr2.forEach(e2 => {
        arr3.forEach(e3 => {
            result[result.length] = e1 + e2 + e3;
        });
    });
});


console.log(result);
/*
output:
[
  'apx', 'apy', 'apz', 'aqx',
  'aqy', 'aqz', 'arx', 'ary',
  'arz', 'bpx', 'bpy', 'bpz',
  'bqx', 'bqy', 'bqz', 'brx',
  'bry', 'brz', 'cpx', 'cpy',
  'cpz', 'cqx', 'cqy', 'cqz',
  'crx', 'cry', 'crz'
]
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without recursion, which also includes a function to retrieve a single combination by its id:

```js
function getCombination(data, i) {
    return data.map(group => {
        let choice = group[i % group.length]
        i = (i / group.length) | 0;
        return choice;
    });
}

function* combinations(data) {
    let count = data.reduce((sum, {length}) => sum * length, 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        yield getCombination(data, i);
    }
}

let data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']];

for (let combination of combinations(data)) {
    console.log(...combination);
}
```