# For loop in multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array

Since now, I'm using this loop to iterate over the elements of an array, which works fine even if I put objects with various properties inside of it.

```
var cubes[];

for (i in cubes){
     cubes[i].dimension
     cubes[i].position_x
     ecc..
}
```

Now, let's suppose cubes[] is declared this way

```
var cubes[][];
```

Can I do this in JavaScript? How can I then automatically iterate in

```
cubes[0][0]
cubes[0][1]
cubes[0][2]
cubes[1][0]
cubes[1][1]
cubes[1][2]
cubes[2][0]
ecc...
```

As a workaround, I can just declare:

```
var cubes[];
var cubes1[];
```

and work separately with the two arrays. Is this a better solution?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var cubes = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],    
 [7, 8, 9],
];

for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    var cube = cubes[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
        display("cube[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + cube[j]);
    }
}
```

Working jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/TRR4n/

The output of the above:

```
cube[0][0] = 1
cube[0][1] = 2
cube[0][2] = 3
cube[1][0] = 4
cube[1][1] = 5
cube[1][2] = 6
cube[2][0] = 7
cube[2][1] = 8
cube[2][2] = 9
```

Comment: Your solution only works with 2D arrays, but I've found a way to loop through arrays with any number of dimensions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854485/975097

Comment: @AndersonGreen OP was specifically looking for 2D arrays, thus the above answer. Thanks for the link though - hope it helps someone looking for a similar solution in the future!

Comment: @Bharadwaj That's a whole new question - see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-permuations-of-javascript-array-values

Comment: Using **ES6**, this can be re-written way shorter using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717414/5625547) for an example.

Answer (score 24):

```
var cubes = [["string", "string"], ["string", "string"]];

for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < cubes[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(cubes[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: And he asked "Can I do this in javascript?"

Comment: You edited your answer after my comment.  Your original post had nothing about iteration.

Answer (score 18):

A bit too late, but this solution is nice and neat

```
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
for (let i of arr) {
  for (let j of i) {
    console.log(j) //Should log numbers from 1 to 10
  }
}
```

Or in your case:

```
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for (let [d1, d2, d3] of arr) {
  console.log(`${d1}, ${d2}, ${d3}`) //Should return numbers from 1 to 9
}
```

**Note:** `for ... of` loop is standardised in ES6, so only use this if you have an ES5 Javascript Complier (such as Babel)

**Another note:** There are alternatives, but they have some subtle differences and behaviours, such as `forEach()`, `for...in`, `for...of` and traditional `for()`. It depends on your case to decide which one to use. (ES6 also has `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.find()`, `.reduce()`)

Comment: There is a mistake: `standardised in ES6, so only use this if you have an ES5`, it should be `ES6`. Further, in `another note` you mention `for ... of` again.

Answer (score 8):

An efficient way to loop over an Array is the [built-in array method .map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

For a 1-dimensional array it would look like this:

```
function HandleOneElement( Cuby ) {
   Cuby.dimension
   Cuby.position_x
   ...
}
cubes.map(HandleOneElement) ; // the map function will pass each element
```

for 2-dimensional array:

```
cubes.map( function( cubeRow ) { cubeRow.map( HandleOneElement ) } )
```

for an n-dimensional array of any form:

```
Function.prototype.ArrayFunction = function(param) {
  if (param instanceof Array) {
    return param.map( Function.prototype.ArrayFunction, this ) ;
  }
  else return (this)(param) ;
}
HandleOneElement.ArrayFunction(cubes) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var i, j;

for (i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cubes[i].length; j++) {
       do whatever with cubes[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: That will create global variables.

Comment: Added var i, j;  In fairness, he didn't say, "Don't create global variables." ;-)

Comment: Why declaring i and j on a new line whilst you can do it in the loop? `for(var i = 0; ...)`

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do this alternatively with "forEach()":

```
var cubes = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],    
 [7, 8, 9],
];

cubes.forEach(function each(item) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    // If is array, continue repeat loop
    item.forEach(each);
  } else {
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

If you need array's index, please try this code:

```
var i = 0; j = 0;

cubes.forEach(function each(item) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    // If is array, continue repeat loop
    item.forEach(each);
    i++;
    j = 0;
  } else {
    console.log("[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + item);
    j++;
  }
});
```

And the result will look like this:

```
[0][0] = 1
[0][1] = 2
[0][2] = 3
[1][0] = 4
[1][1] = 5
[1][2] = 6
[2][0] = 7
[2][1] = 8
[2][2] = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ES2015 and you want to define your own object that iterates like a 2-D array, you can implement the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) by:

1. Defining an *@@iterator* function called `Symbol.iterator` which returns...
2. ...an object with a `next()` function that returns...
3. ...an object with one or two properties: an optional `value` with the next value (if there is one) and a boolean `done` which is true if we're done iterating.

A *one-dimensional* array iterator function would look like this:

```
// our custom Cubes object which implements the iterable protocol
function Cubes() {
    this.cubes = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    this.numVals = this.cubes.length;

    // assign a function to the property Symbol.iterator
    // which is a special property that the spread operator
    // and for..of construct both search for
    this[Symbol.iterator] = function () { // can't take args

        var index = -1; // keep an internal count of our index
        var self = this; // access vars/methods in object scope

        // the @@iterator method must return an object
        // with a "next()" property, which will be called
        // implicitly to get the next value
        return {
            // next() must return an object with a "done" 
            // (and optionally also a "value") property
            next: function() {
                index++;
                // if there's still some values, return next one
                if (index < self.numVals) {
                    return {
                        value: self.cubes[index],
                        done: false
                    };
                }
                // else there's no more values left, so we're done
                // IF YOU FORGET THIS YOU WILL LOOP FOREVER!
                return {done: true}
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Now, we can treat our `Cubes` object like an iterable:

```
var cube = new Cubes(); // construct our cube object

// both call Symbol.iterator function implicitly:
console.log([...cube]); // spread operator
for (var value of cube) { // for..of construct
    console.log(value);
}
```

To create our own *2-D* iterable, instead of returning a value in our `next()` function, we can return another iterable:

```
function Cubes() {
    this.cubes = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
    ];
    this.numRows = this.cubes.length;
    this.numCols = this.cubes[0].length; // assumes all rows have same length

    this[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
        var row = -1;
        var self = this;

        // create a closure that returns an iterator
        // on the captured row index
        function createColIterator(currentRow) {
            var col = -1;
            var colIterator = {}
            // column iterator implements iterable protocol
            colIterator[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
                return {next: function() {
                    col++;
                    if (col < self.numCols) {
                        // return raw value
                        return {
                            value: self.cubes[currentRow][col],
                            done: false
                        };
                    }
                    return {done: true};
                }};
            }
            return colIterator;
        }

        return {next: function() {
            row++;
            if (row < self.numRows) {
                // instead of a value, return another iterator
                return {
                    value: createColIterator(row),
                    done: false
                };
            }
            return {done: true}
        }};
    };
}
```

Now, we can use nested iteration:

```
var cube = new Cubes();

// spread operator returns list of iterators, 
// each of which can be spread to get values
var rows = [...cube];
console.log([...rows[0]]);
console.log([...rows[1]]);
console.log([...rows[2]]);

// use map to apply spread operator to each iterable
console.log([...cube].map(function(iterator) { 
    return [...iterator];
}));

for (var row of cube) {
    for (var value of row) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Note that our custom iterable won't behave like a 2-D array in all cases; for example, we haven't implemented a `map()` function. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28718967/6157047) shows how you could implement a generator map function ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) for the difference between iterators and generators; also, generators are an ES2016 feature, not ES2015, so you'll need to [change your babel presets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await/42495576#42495576) if you're compiling with babel).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have such declarations.  It would be:

```
var cubes = ...
```

regardless

But you can do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++)
{
  for(var j = 0; j < cubes[i].length; j++)
  {

  }
}
```

Note that JavaScript allows jagged arrays, like:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
]
```

since arrays can contain any type of object, including an array of arbitrary length.

As noted by [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> "for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important"

If you use your original syntax, there is no guarantee the elements will be visited in numeric order.

Answer (score 1):

#### ES6 variant using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

<sup>Based on [icyrock.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021901/5625547)'s
answer.</sup>

```js
const cubes = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],    
   [7, 8, 9]
];

cubes.forEach((n, i) => {
    n.forEach((b, j) => {
        console.log(`cubes[${i}][${j}] = ${b}`);
    });
});
```