# Javascript For loop in multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dimensional

Can anyone give me a sample/example of JavaScript with a multidimensional array of inputs? Hope you could help because I'm still new to the JavaScript.

Like this:

```
 var cubes =   [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];

output : [1,4,7],
         [1,4,8],
         [1,4,9],
         [1,5,7],
         [1,5,8],
         [1,5,9],
         [1,6,7],
         [1,6,8],
         [1,6,8],
        ......... 
        .........
         [3,6,7],
         [3,6,8],
         [3,6,9]
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to loop over a single array ?

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```
var cubes = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];

for(var i=0; i<cubes[0].length; ++i)
for(var j=0; j<cubes[1].length; ++j)
for(var k=0; k<cubes[2].length; ++k) {
    alert([cubes[0][i],cubes[1][j],cubes[2][k]]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution only works for 3-dimensional arrays. However, I've found a way to loop through arrays with any number of dimensions (which may be more useful): http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854485/975097

Answer (score 1):

This works for the given array, but means if you have more than three inner arrays, or more array dimensions then you would have to manually edit the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cubes =   [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];
    var output = "";

    for(var a = 0; a < cubes[0].length; a++)
    for(var b = 0; b < cubes[1].length; b++)
    for(var c = 0; c < cubes[2].length; c++) {
        output = output + [cubes[0][a],cubes[1][b],cubes[2][c]] + ",<br />";
    }

    $('#output').html(output);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HtSkd/