# babel 6 async / await: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Im having trouble getting async / await transforms working.
What am I missing?

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ]
}
```

My package.json (snipped):

```
{  
  "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2"
}
```

Output:

```
babel src/server
SyntaxError: src/server/index.js: Unexpected token (7:21)
   5 |
   6 | try {
>  7 |   let server = await server('localhost', env.NODE_PORT || 3000)
     |                      ^
   8 |   console.log(`Server started on ${server.info.uri}`)
   9 | } catch (err) {
  10 |   console.error('Error starting server: ', err)
```

Comment: Your configuration may be limiting loaders to a specific folder like 'client'.  Check the includes options for the loader.

Answer (score 12):

According to this post you need to have `babel-polyfill`

[Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hopefully it'll help you :)

EDIT:

It doesn't have to be babel-polyfill but it's the only one I used.

As Gothdo said: the `await` keyword has to be in a function scope. Moreover, this function definition has to have the `async` keyword.

This means that you can not have the `await` keyword on the top-level scope.

Comment: I am already requiring the package babel-polyfill, it still errors out

Comment: Is your `await` line in a function scope ? I'm not sure but it seems that it's not working outside of a function marked with `async`.

Comment: @legomind but it is not listed in your package.json (that you posted at least) `"babel-polyfill": "^6.0.16",`

Comment: Hello. @legomind, did you manage to get this working somehow?

Comment: Just using babel with stage-0 and es2015 preset works for me as long as you import `babel-polyfill` in your entry point. As BrunoLM said, make sure you have the module installed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like async/await is only available in `babel-preset-stage-3`

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/

Comment: Excuse me, but isn't [stage-0](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) supposed to contain stage-3?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile them yourself using the `transform-async-to-module-method` plugin, this allows you to compile them down to bluebird co-routines which requires ES6 generators (available in node4).

Or if you need to compile it back to ES5 so it's compatible for browsers you can use `transform-async-to-generator` and facebook's `regenerator`.

I've written about how to set up your babel config here http://madole.xyz/async-await-es7/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Async to generator transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/).

## Installation

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator
```

## Usage

Add the following line to your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to upgrade to Babel 7 and use babel-env as opposed to stages (see here: https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade).

There's a command you can use to upgrade accordingly:

```
npx babel-upgrade
```