# babel ES7 Async - regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm using browserify + gulp + babel in my project, and having problem with ES7 features. These are what I installed:

- babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator@6.8.0
- babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4  // for use decorators
- babel-polyfill@6.9.1
- babel-preset-es2015@6.9.0
- babel-preset-es2016@6.11.0
- babel-preset-stage-0@6.5.0
- babelify@7.3.0
- browserify@13.0.1
- gulp
- gulp-sourcemaps
- vinyl-buffer
- vinyl-source-stream

and this is my gulp code:

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
    let buildPath;
    let destPath;

    buildPath = `./src`;
    destPath = `./dist`;

    return browserify(`${buildPath}/app.js`)
    .transform(babelify, { 
        presets: ["es2015", "es2016", "stage-0"],
        plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-async-to-generator"]
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${destPath}`));
});
```

and this is my js code:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

// Async Functions
function wait(t) {
    return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, t));
}

async function asyncMania() {
    console.log('1');
    await wait(1000);
    console.log('2');
}

asyncMania().then(() => console.log('3'));
```

When I try this, gets an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Using **require** instead of **import** doesn't work either. Most of questions are using Webpack, not browserify and other approaches were not worked on me, so it will be very appreciate tell me how should I do.

And I have one more question, as you can see, I installed babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-es2016 both, and both are using. If I remove **es2015** plugin, can I still use ES6 features? And also I included **babel-preset-stage-0**, and as I know this is for experimental ES7 features. What actually **babel-preset-es2016** got?

Comment: I installed **transform-regenerator** plugin and **transform-async-functions**, still don't work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have same error and fix it by using "babel-plugin-transform-runtime".
hope this also work for you.

[Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await)

Comment: I solved this with latest babel + async plugins + babel-polyfill. Thanks.

Comment: This is great! I didn't even need babel-polyfill to make this work.