# How to run aurelia-plugins/aurelia-plugins-google-places-autocomplete locally

Tags: aurelia, babeljs

I have installed this aurelia plugin in my project: https://github.com/aurelia-plugins/aurelia-plugins-google-places-autocomplete which is basically an Aurelia wrapper for google places autocomplete.

Unfortunately I'm experience a "regeneratorRuntime is not defined" issue when using it (It has been reported in the repo). And the reason seems to be the way that async/await are transpiled. I have found a possible solution to fix the issue as seen here: [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await)

I have cloned the repo and installed now I just need to be able to run it locally to test it out. Does someone know how I can run that repo locally. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Usually what I do when I want to test a plugin is I will create test project where I run the plugin as a feature. Features work just like plugins except they are local to your project's structure. Instead of doing

```
aurelia.use
  .plugin('aurelia-plugins-google-places-autocomplete', config => { \\...
```

You will do

```
aurelia.use
  .feature('aurelia-plugins-google-places-autocomplete', config => { \\...
```

This is assuming you place the plugin in `src\aurelia-plugins-google-places-autocomplete`.

This is a story that I would like to see us come up with a pattern for. Maybe we'll add something to the `skeleton-plugin` project that will help with this.