# React.js set callback function after execution of first function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, redux, react-redux

I have been calling an api on onClick event of my React.js/Redux app. After calling the api, I have to call another api based on the results of first API. So I was thinking about async calls.

My code:

```
<a href="" onClick={(e) => this.sendData(e)} >Send</a>
```

and method sendData is

```
sendData(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.sendDataApi({this.refs.msg.value});
    //After receiving results from above api, i have to call another api async
    this.props.getDetails(this.refs.txt.value);
}
```

But currenlty both APIs called at the same time. Any help!

Comment: the best place to handle async calls with redux is directly in action creator. I mean wait for result of async call in action creator

Comment: is there a way to do via callback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using async/await pattern which handles that scenario well. Your code would then look like this:

```
const sendData = async message => {
    const messageId = await sendDataApi(message)
    const details = await getDetails(messageId)
    return details
}
```

However, if you are not able to use newest language features you may use `Promise`s. Keep in mind that the code will be more prone to callback-hell and that they might also need polyfilling.

The same code with promises would look like this:

```
const sendData = message => {
    sendDataApi(message)
    .then(messageId => getDetails(messageId))
}
```

This code is a mere example of the issues with Promises because it can be reduced just to `sendDataApi(message).then(getDetails)`. Problems arise when there are complex conditional logic, error handling, more tasks, and parameter passing.

React handles asynchrony very poorly so do the Redux. You need to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or another middleware. With that, you will be able to dispatch another action from the action creator  (`continuation`, `trunk`, `saga` - you name it). It can become tedious, require much boilerplate, and be very difficult to debug. You may consider leaving Redux synchronous state management and consider other solutions ([RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) maybe?) for those kinds of problems.

Please [see an example of using Promises to chain two asynchronous calls](http://mikelambert.me/react/#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) using React's default `setState` (see console output).

With [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) the implementation might look like this (other actions not show, no error handling etc.):

```
...

const sendData = message => {
  return dispatch => {
    return sendDataApi(message).then(
      messageId => dispatch(getDetails(messageId)),
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, I will use this to resolve my problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: I used async, await technique, and it worked. Thanks again. For those who see this question in future, please use `babel-polyfill` as it is required to use async, await in React. For reference check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await