# Symbol.iterator: get all the object's properties in iterator object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, symbols

I am currently reading about [Symbols and Iterators](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-iterators-in-depth#iterator-protocol-and-iterable-protocol) (ES6 features) and after running into an example there, I am trying to make an object iterable so that I can use `for...of` feature. From few examples/answers here/articles I checked, it looks like this in plain case:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 5,
  prop2: 'test',
  prop3: new Date(),
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => ({
  items: obj.items,
  next: function next() {
    return {
        done: this.items.length === 0,
        value: this.items.shift()
      }
  }
  })
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "items", {
  enumerable: false,
  get: function() {
      let props = [];
      for(let prop in this) if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) props.push(this[prop]);
      return props;
  }
});
for(let prop of obj) console.log(prop);
```

But I find it annoying to list manually all the values of an object's properties in `items` array of iterator. Also it feels dirty and messy with `Object.defineProperty`. I am kind of trying tom expand the example from the [link](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-iterators-in-depth#iterator-protocol-and-iterable-protocol). Is there a smarter/simpler way to get all the object's properties inside iterator (instead of `items: obj.items` and related bloat or manually listing items like `items: [5, 'test', new Date()]`)?

Comment: Why did you think you needed an `.items` getter property for this?

Comment: well, first off, I needed to set `enumerable: false` to avoid appearing this property itself in the list; also to make the object cleaner.

Comment: Don't make objects iterable, there's no point. Instead, just write `for (let prop in obj) console.log(prop);` - that's what `for … in` loops are good for!

Comment: No, why did you think you needed `obj.items` at all?

Comment: I needed it to get the array of actual values for iterator method.

Comment: sure, you are right about `for...in` being useful for objects. I just tried to implement Symbol.iterator stuff with learning purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a generator in the symbol iterator maybe:

```
[Symbol.iterator]:function*(){
    for(value of Object.values(this)){
      yield value;//may extend this to your needs
    }
 }
```

Or in your case:

```
[Symbol.iterator]:function*(){
  var i=1;
  while(this["prop"+i]){
      yield this["prop"+i];//may extend this to your needs
      i++;
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/zekunalusi/edit?console

Comment: That creates infinite recursion as `of` tries to iterate the object…

Comment: @bergi oh right, does Object.values() use the iterator (i hope not)?

Comment: That'll work, `Object.values` enumerates the properties

Comment: I tried your second alternative. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

Comment: sorry, it works on jsbin, but fails on codepen where I test

Comment: @curveball i bet its a problem in your babel environment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-with-async-await

Comment: @Jonas w I like the idea with generators since they return iterator object which is expected by `for...of`. Although in this case the whole thing seems to be senseless because  it is easier to use `for...in` from the beginning.

Comment: @curveball yeah i think there are very rare usecases for  generators and iterators, and this isnt one in my opinion ( you could simply do for(value in obj.items), but thats another question ;)

Comment: @Jonas w yeah, totally agree. I just was reading an article with such an example of usecase. Check it out if interested:
https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-iterators-in-depth#iterator-protocol-and-iterable-protocol

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an `items` getter but instead just create the array inside the iterator method. Also you can use generator syntax to create the iterator, which is much easier.

But the simplest way to achieve what you want is

```
let obj = {
  prop1: 5,
  prop2: 'test',
  prop3: new Date(),
  [Symbol.iterator]() { return Object.keys(this).map(k => this[k])[Symbol.iterator](); }
};
```

Comment: when I tried this with `for..of` I got `Object.values(...).values is not a function` error.

Comment: Oh, right, [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) is still experimental. I'll update

Comment: now it says `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys(...).map(...).values is not a function`

Comment: @curveball Apparently browsers are lagging behind to support [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) because of compat problems. Fortunately the same method exists under a different name :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function objectEntries(obj) {
    let index = 0;

    // In ES6, you can use strings or symbols as property keys,
    // Reflect.ownKeys() retrieves both
    let propKeys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);

    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            if (index < propKeys.length) {
                let key = propKeys[index];
                index++;
                return { value: [key, obj[key]] };
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        }
    };
}

let obj = { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' };
for (let [key,value] of objectEntries(obj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html