# Async Await + Gulp - GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, async-await

This is the part in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('compile-js', function () {
    // app.js is your main JS file with all your module inclusions
  return browserify({
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    entries: 'javascripts/app.js',
    debug: true
  })
  .transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.min.js'))
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(livereload())
})
```

in my `javascripts/app.js`:

I have, for an example:

```
async function write () {
    var txt = await read();
    console.log(txt);
  }
```

I get this error:

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
```

This is part of my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "aos": "^2.2.0",
    "autosize": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "es6-docready": "^1.0.0",
    "foundation-icon-fonts": "^0.1.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.3",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-cssimport": "^5.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.12.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "swiper": "^3.4.2",
    "vue": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "[git-url-of-your-project]"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.12",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-clone": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-cssimport": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.2",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "streamqueue": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

What else should I add to my gulp process for ES6?

**EDIT:**

so following the babel [doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/) for es2017:

I have installed:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2017
```

And changed my gulpfile:

```
...
.transform('babelify', {
    presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'react'],
```

I don't get any error during the compilation, but I get this error on the browser console when I run my code on my browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Comment: async/await is es2017. You need the corresponding Babel preset

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I get a new error, pls see my edit above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had similar issue with gulp-uglify, and as I've found out it seems that minifying async/await is not supported with base `gulp-uglify`, so I switched to [babel-minify](https://github.com/babel/minify), and it worked for me.

EDIT: For `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` error, I think that [regenerator-runtime](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/tree/master/packages/regenerator-runtime) could be helpful.

Comment: I had the same problem. Since then I switched back to callbacks to solve my problem and I still can use gulp-uglify.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem replacing:

**`.pipe(uglify())`** by **`.pipe(minify())`**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify