# HtmlWebpackPlugin does not include vendor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to improve the loading speed of our website.
So I have been putting my hands into our webpack.config.

After several modification I now get the modules separated and hashed properly.
I am also using HtmlWebpackPlugin to automatically generate the index.html from out template.

But I got a couple of other issues appearing as well.

1. vendor.js is not added automatically to the template. Only the chunk-manifest.json and index.[hash].js are added automatically. If I try to load directly like that I get a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

2. After adding vendor.js manually I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

This is the webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

/* Shared Dev & Production */

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  entry: {
    index: './index.js',
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-redux', 'history', 'react-router-dom', 'redux', 'react-router-redux', 'redux-form', 'lodash'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
              publicPath: '/'
            }
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.xml/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },

  plugins: [
    // New moment.js optimization
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ['vendor'],
            filename: '[name].js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),

    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      appMountId: 'app-root',
      inlineManifestWebpackName: 'webpackManifest',
      template: 'templateIndex.html',
      title: 'Our Site',
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  config.plugins = [
    ...config.plugins,
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
  ];
//}

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].js';
  config.plugins = [
    ...config.plugins,
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new WebpackChunkHash(),
    new ChunkManifestPlugin({
      filename: 'chunk-manifest.json',
      manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
      inlineManifest: true,
    }),
  ];
//}

module.exports = config;
```

At this point I am not sure what is wrong with the webpack.config.

How can I get the vendor.js to be automatically added?

This is the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title itemprop="name">Our Site</title>

  <base href="/">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/images/favicon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/images/favicon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/favicon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/images/favicon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/images/favicon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/images/favicon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/images/favicon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/images/favicon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/favicon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">

  <link type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.png" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">

  <noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the .babelrc (I think the regeneratorRuntime is related to it, just need to figure out how)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      { "modules": false }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-0",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [ "syntax-dynamic-import", "transform-react-jsx", "transform-decorators-legacy" ]
}
```

From what I have read online the regenerator error is due to conflicting packaging. But I do not see where that comes from.

Comment: Can you please share your `templateIndex.html` as well?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't seem there was anything in there that could've caused the problem, but I dug in a bit more and have a working webpack config below, though it required dropping the use of the `ChunkManifestPlugin`. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have updated my webpack with what you suggested. The vendor is now automatically added. But I still get the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined' error. I will see what I can find about it.

Comment: Hmm, I'll see what I can figure out as well. It works fine on my end, but I'm just using a very basic `index.js` for my `index` entry point and only including `react` in the `vendor` entry point. So, that at least narrows down your search a little bit.

Comment: I have added the babelrc code as well because I think it is the source of the problem. At least accoding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: I think your `.babelrc` is fine actually. You may want to try adding `babel-polyfill` to your index entry point. I'm pretty confident this will take care of it.

Comment: See the upvoted answer on that S/O thread you shared. He also recommends the best practice of using `babel-preset-env`, though from my experience you will have some trouble getting it to work with React.

Comment: I've updated my answer below with the `babel-polyfill` included.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot for all your help :)

Comment: Glad to help and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`

is usually a result of missing Webpack code that is extracted by `CommonsChunkPlugin`. You may need to verify that this file is being injected properly as well.

## Solution

I was able to get this working by removing the `ChunkManifestPlugin`. It seems there is a conflict between it and `CommonsChunkPlugin`. Something I've not experienced in the past, myself, but check out what I've done below, which does the trick:

**Note:** You will also need to include `babel-polyfill` to get the regenerator-runtime working in the browser.

## First:

#### Babel 6

`npm install --save babel-polyfill`

#### Babel 7

`npm install --save @babel/polyfill`

## Then:

#### Diff:

```
8a9,11
> // To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
> require('babel-polyfill'); // or @babel/polyfill if Babel 7
> 
15c18,22
<     index: './index.js',
---
>     index: [
>       // To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
>       'babel-polyfill', // or @babel/polyfill if Babel 7
>       './index.js'
>     ],
82d88
<       filename: '[name].js',
114c120
<   new ChunkManifestPlugin({
---
>   /*new ChunkManifestPlugin({
118c124
<   }),
---
>   }),*/
```

#### Full webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

// To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
require('babel-polyfill'); // or @babel/polyfill if Babel 7

/* Shared Dev & Production */

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  entry: {
    index: [
      // To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
      'babel-polyfill', // or @babel/polyfill if Babel 7
      './index.js'
    ],
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-redux', 'history', 'react-router-dom', 'redux', 'react-router-redux', 'redux-form', 'lodash'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
              publicPath: '/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {name: '[name].[ext]'},
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.xml/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {name: '[name].[ext]'},
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },

  plugins: [
    // New moment.js optimization
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      appMountId: 'app-root',
      inlineManifestWebpackName: 'webpackManifest',
      template: 'templateIndex.html',
      title: 'Our Site',
    }),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
config.plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
];
//}

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].js';
config.plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
  new WebpackChunkHash(),
  /*new ChunkManifestPlugin({
    filename: 'chunk-manifest.json',
    manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
    inlineManifest: true,
  }),*/
];
//}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I added the template as you asked

Comment: The reason I am creating the vendor entry point is because I am using [this](https://www.codementor.io/drewpowers/high-performance-webpack-config-for-front-end-delivery-90sqic1qa) (referring to #5 specifically) as a reference to speed up the loading of the front page.