# async / await breaks my Webpack build for AWS Lambda; how can I migrate to Node 8.10?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda

*Note: this is a Q&A on migrating AWS Lambda Webpack builds from v6.10 to v8.10 — no help is needed, but even better answers are of course always encouraged!*

---

For a while now I have been a disciple of using Webpack to build my back-end Lambdas after reading James Long's excellent series entitled *"Backend Apps with Webpack"* ([part 1](https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I), [part2](https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-II), and [part3](https://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-III)).

Up until recently, the only version of Node.js that [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) offered was 6.10; you had to write your Lambda fn in the "callback" style. But on April 2, 2018 [AWS announced that 8.10 was now supported](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/), and with it the suggested pattern is async / await which is great! Until it immediately broke my Webpack build. After a bit of debugging, I can break my build just by adding one async fn to the Lambda handler (I don't even need to call it):

```
async function firstAsync() {
  return true;
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    return 'Hello from Lambda!'
};
```

To be clear, doing this in the AWS Lambda console is perfectly fine, runs great. Webpack even builds it successfully, but upon uploading to AWS Lambda, I get the following error message: `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.  My code is below. What am I needing to do?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'index',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  target: 'node', // building for a Node environment
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder 
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lambda-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An empty project scaffold to enable webpack builds in AWS Lambda",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "upload": "upload.bat"
  },
  "author": "Geek Stocks®",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.179.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin using async / await in your Webpack-built code, you need a little help from Babel, specfically the `babel-runtime` and the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`. Fortunately there is a really good writeup on the installation and use of both [here on the Babel website](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/). You need Babel to do the following for you:

> Automatically requires babel-runtime/regenerator when you use
>   generators/async functions.

I won't repeat what has been written there, **however**, of particular note is HOW you need to install these, because while their writeup certainly works for most, there is a needed tweak for some AWS Lambda devs who have not needed runtime `dependencies` before now.

The first part is pretty normal, you need new devDependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

And also you need to tweak your `.babelrc` file like they describe:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "helpers": false,
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true,
      "moduleName": "babel-runtime"
    }]
  ]
}
```

But here is the kicker, and this is new to the code above: the `babel-runtime` is a regular `dependencies`, not a `devDependencies`:

```
npm install --save babel-runtime
```

These 2 installs and the `.babelrc` tweaks do SOLVE the async / await problem described above, but it introduces a new problem to the build above: `Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/regenerator'`.

If you are at all concerned with keeping your Webpack built code small, you are likely also using [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) like the above code does. For example, the [aws-sdk for JavaScript in Node](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) is very large and is already available in the Lambda environment, so its superfluous to bundle it again. The `webpack-node-externals` configuration above configures Webpack to ignore ALL the modules in `node-modules` by default, and *there* is the root of the new problem. The newly installed `babel-runtime` is a module that needs to be bundled in the build in order for Lambda to run correctly.

Understanding the problem then, the answer becomes simple: don't use the default configuration. Instead of passing in nothing to `webpack-node-externals`, configure it like this:

```
externals: [nodeExternals({
  whitelist: [
    'babel-runtime/regenerator',
    'regenerator-runtime'
  ]
})], // ignore all modules in node_modules folder EXCEPT the whitelist
```

And **that** solves both the original async / await problem, and the (possible) new problem you may be encountering if you had no previous `dependencies` in your build. Hope that helps — happy Lambda `await`ing!

Comment: This process is for Node v4.3 and v6.10 runtimes.

Comment: I somewhat agree. The first step towards migrating from 6.10 to 8.10 is to first assess whether or not you can refactor to eliminate Babel entirely as dashmug correctly states in his answer. *Its a much nicer result.* But if you cannot avoid Babel for other reasons however, this answer _does_ work for 8.10 as well, *if* you follow Babel's recommendation for `.babelrc` shown here. Testing proved this, and failed when using the Babel config in dashmug's answer. That item withstanding, we do seem to have 2 useful answers here, depending on one's environment. Thank you dashmug :)

Comment: This still works in Node 8.10 because what you wrote for earlier versions will continue to work on it. But with this configuration, you are NOT using Node 8's `async/await` features since Babel will convert it to a generator. So, you're not really migrating to Node 8 as the OP question states.

Comment: This answer answers the question "How can I use async/await on Node 4 and 6 runtimes?".

Answer (score 3):

Geek Stock's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49939402/1252647) is only necessary when using the Node v6.10 runtime. It allows you to use `async/await` syntax and `babel-runtime/regenerator` converts your async functions to ES6 generators which is supported on Node v4.3.2 and newer runtimes.

In Node v8.10 though, it is different. `async/await` is already supported so you don't need Babel to convert your `async` functions to generators. You just use it correctly and it works.

As for your specific situation, I assume you simply changed your Javascript code to use `async/await` code but you didn't tell Babel NOT to convert your `async/await` code to generators. That is why `babel-runtime` is complaining about a missing plugin.

If this is the case, you simply need to configure Babel to simply target Node v8.10. You can do it like this in your `.babelrc`...

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "8.10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`babel` will then stop converting those `async` functions. And since it's not doing a conversion, it will not need the `regenerator-runtime` anymore.

Comment: The code in OP's question is a Babel build. Are you answering this migration question by suggesting the removal of Babel altogether? It seems your answer is to reconfigure Babel differently that what Babel's advice is in their writeup. I've done a git rollback and migrated again using your method, and the same error has appeared (`regeneratorRuntime is not defined`). Its not clear then what you are saying. I will try removing Babel altogether, which would be better if possible.

Comment: Again, you only need the `regenerator-runtime` when you're building for Node versions less than 8. If `async/await` is your only use case for Babel, then you can remove it altogether when targeting Node v8. My answer is about keeping Babel if you still need it. If you only use `async/await`, then removing Babel is better if you're targeting Node v8.10.

Comment: Tip: Make sure you're also using Node v8.10 on your development machine and in your CI environment if you have any.

Comment: I agree. A 2 hour code refactoring session has now taken place (lol), and after some changes I was able to build and deploy to Lambda 8.10 successfully without Babel at all. In Lambda 6.10 and prior, developers will need my answer as you pointed out. But definitely if developers can move away from Babel entirely, the result is a very streamlined build.

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Using `serverless-webpack` as well for a lambda in node 8.10, I expect Babel not to transpile my `async/await`. But it does transpile them, and as I removed the `babel-runtime/regenerator` when upgrading to node 8, I am having this error: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

- Babel config targets `node 8.10` (nothing else)
- devDependencies: `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env`, `webpack` and `webpack-node-externals`
- dependencies: `@babel/runtime`

Comment: @herve What `node` version do you use on the machine that does the transpilation? And what's in your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Thank you @dashmug! node version `v8.10.0`, a link to a gist `webpack.config.js`: https://gist.github.com/HerveNivon/3d33f2697d817552e37409ce0e7250a6 (code doesn't work well in comment, sorry for the link to follow)

Comment: @herve What about your babelrc?

Comment: @dashmug, same than the one you shared: `{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "8.10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}`

Comment: Have no idea what's wrong with yours. If you have a public repo that reproduces the problem, I can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I'm using it with `nodejs12.x`. I'm receiving the error **regeneratorRuntime is not defined**.

I was using preset `es2015` and `stage-0` with a `node12.x` code. Also I'm using an older version of `babel`.

What I did, installed:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
"@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2"
```

And then set this babel preset:

```
"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"targets": { "node": "current" }}]
]
```

Thanks,