# node.js async await - error regeneratorRuntime

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, babeljs

I learnt how to use promises in a browser but when I want to use it in my node.js it throw error.

```
 var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(url) {
                                           ^
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

node version

```
v10.4.1
```

I use babel for export and import syntax with settings like here in starting file

```
require('babel-register')({ 
    presets: [ 'env' ]
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-polyfill` is required. You must also install it in order to get async/await working.

Here explain better [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: @AlexMontoya why do we need this to use async/await on Node 10 when it's natively supported?

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to use `async/await` and for me this worked out.

In your babel file include this.

```
presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ]  ]
```

Comment: Best to use if you are running the latest version of babel 7+

Comment: I have tried many ways but this work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are trying to use `async` / `await` syntax? You will need to install [transform-async-to-generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator) plugin and include it in your Babel config

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: ['env'],
  plugins: ['transform-async-to-generator']
})
```

Comment: why do we need this to use async/await on Node 10 when it's natively supported?

Comment: @HRK44 because unless you stipulate otherwise, Babel will transpile modern features for backward compatibility

Comment: how to "stipulate otherwise" ? :D

Comment: @HRK44 by setting the correct [target](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets) for your environment.

Comment: thanks I'll look into it, but I think I have it already set up as node 10. I'll double check

Comment: @HRK44 did it work for you with target set as node10, It did not work for me.

Comment: @James I used following `"babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }`

Comment: OK it worked I seems like issue was in my build script where I was building using npm script `babel src --out-dir build --presets=@babel/preset-env` I just remove --presets part and it worked ok

Comment: @Yalamber no problem, was just racking my brains unless there was something else missing but your config looked good. Glad you got it working :) If you inspect your compiled file now you should see `async` / `await` will be in there and not transpiled.

Comment: @Yalamber I think it did not work for me, I ended up using some other kind of babel plugins

Comment: @HRK44 try looking in to all possible configuration of babel, if you have set proper target it should work. It woked for me by setting target to node current as my current node version supports async await out of the box.

Comment: @james indeed, it worked after I removed the preset part from the build script. seems like it was overriding the configuration.