# Return array from fetched WMS GetCapabilities request

Tags: javascript, arrays, openlayers, wms

I'm trying to return an array of time values from a WMS Layer I have to populate a dropdown menu in Openlayers. I have been able to get a list of time values in the layer inside a function (and print this output to the console in the function), but cannot get get this array out of the function. Current code is below:

```
var url = **working_WMS_url**

var GetCaps = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
      var result = GetCaps.read(text);
      var times = result.Capability.LayerLayer[0].Dimension;
      return times;
});
console.log(times);

// Section below links and populates dropdown menu
var time_list = document.getELementById("time_list");

for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    var opt = times[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    time_list.appendChild(el);
}
```

To confirm, the dropdown menu works correctly, I tested with a manually defined set of times. I just can't work out why the list "times" isn't returned from the function.

For clarity, I am relatively new to javascript but not coding in general so apologies if there is a very simple solution to this. I've spent the last hour looking through StackOverflow questions but couldn't find one that answered exactly this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetch operates asynchronously so all processing which depends on the text having been read from the url should be in the final `then` clause of the fetch.

An alternative (not supported on all browsers) is to declare the calling function asynchronous and use an await statement

```
async function myFunction(url, elementId) {

  var GetCaps = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
  var times = await fetch(url).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
      var result = GetCaps.read(text);
      console.log(result);
      var times = result.Capability.Layer.Layer[0].Dimension;
      return times;
  });
  console.log(times);

  // Section below links and populates dropdown menu
  var time_list = document.getElementById(elementId);

  for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
    var opt = times[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    time_list.appendChild(el);
  }
}

myFunction('working_WMS_url', 'time_list');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've amended my code to include this async function but I am no getting the error, `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

Comment: Some environments need a polyfill  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332149/node-js-async-await-error-regeneratorruntime

Comment: Will investigate installing Babel then! (I had wondered why it was in all the Google searches for that error)

Comment: using `import "regenerator-runtime/runtime" `fixed it. Thanks!