# How do I use service workers in parcel?

Tags: babeljs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, parceljs

I have a service worker that comes from my `js/index.js`:

```js
import '../scss/app.scss';
// Detect if service workers enabled
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  try {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('../sw.js');
    console.log('Service Worker Registered');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Service Worker Register Failed');
  }
}
```

and my sw.js in my root directory:

```js
const staticAssets = ['./', 'scss/app.scss', 'js/index.js'];
self.addEventListener('install', async (event) => {
  const cache = await caches.open('min-static');
  cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.log('fetch');
});
```

Is babelized and put into the dist folder by parcel. When it's built and I go to `localhost`, I open chrome tools and go into the application tab. I go into the cache storage tab and:
[image: Cache Storage just has a heading that says cache storage. There's also a console error that says ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined]
What's going on? Why doesn't my website get nicely cached like in [The PWA Tutorial](https://youtu.be/gcx-3qi7t7c?t=1329)?
Shouldn't it look like this:
[image: A nice table of the cached files that I DON'T HAVE]?
Granted, I am running everything through babel, but why isn't it working?

## Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked this SO post where it is related in your error [about regeneratorRuntime running in babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)?

Comment: @jess I did and I resolved the regeneratorRuntime error, but it's still not caching anything :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` happens because Babel (used by Parcel to transpile code) is generating a polyfill for ES6 generators in your build. To disable that (and fix your issue) you need to specify you don't want the generators to be transpiled.

#### Easy fix

An easy way to fix that would be to add the following lines to your package.json:

```
"browserslist": [
  "since 2017-06"
],
```

This makes it so that your build will only attempt to support browser versions released since 2017-06, which do support ES6 generators and therefore do not need polyfills for that feature.

#### Alternatives

You might want to experiment with these values depending on your application's target audience, for example this should also work:

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 3 and_chr versions",
  "last 3 chrome versions",
  "last 3 opera versions",
  "last 3 ios_saf versions",
  "last 3 safari versions"
]
```

#### More information

If you want to check which features are supported by each browser you can check [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-generators).

And if you want to check which options are valid for `browserslint` check [here](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).

There is also more discussion available regarding your specific issue [here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/871).

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty new to Parcel and I am facing the same issue.

After spending a few hours of searching online and I guess it may have something to do with this issue [parcel-bundler/parcel #301:  PWA support](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/301)

Although, there are 2 [plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=parcel-plugin-sw) and 1 [discussion](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/872) which vows to address this issue.
For the time being, I don't see any perfect solution.

If you happen to find some new discovery, please let us know.