# What is the difference between babel-core and @babel/core?

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader, babel-jest

What is the difference between
[babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core)  and [@babel/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core) ?

Are they the same thing but different versions? If not so, when do you use one and when do you use the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Since Babel 7 the Babel team switched to [scoped packages](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/v7-migration#scoped-packages), so you now have to use `@babel/core` instead of `babel-core`.
But in essence, `@babel/core` is just a newer version of `babel-core`.

This is done to make a better distinction which  packages are official and which are third-party.

Comment: do I need both of them or just the newer/older one?

Comment: @mcmxc Since you want only one version of a certain dependency and  `@babel/core` is `v7` of `babel-core`, you should only install one of them (I would install `@babel/core` if it's a new dependency)