# Requires Babel “7.0.0-0” but was loaded with “6.26.3”

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

Whenever, I run the program, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.
    at throwVersionError (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:65:11)
    at Object.assertVersion (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:13:11)
    at _default (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:51:7)
    at E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at Function.memoisePluginContainer (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:113:13)
    at Function.normalisePlugin (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:146:32)
    at E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:184:30
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
    at OptionManager.init (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:50:20)
    at Object.module.exports (E:\ReactJS final\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:173:20)
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
(I also have attached the package.json file here)

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-final",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "it": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@deck.gl/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@deck.gl/mapbox": "^7.1.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.4.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.6.0",
    "@mapbox/react-geocoder": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-install": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "deck.gl": "^7.1.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.7",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.47.0",
    "npm-autoinstaller": "^1.3.1",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.4",
    "raw-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-geocoder-mapbox": "^2.5.12",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^1.1.2",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.0.3",
    "react-map-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.5",
    "react-mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^1.0.3",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-ga": "^1.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-text-loop": "^2.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uikit": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`, just to make sure everything is ok

Comment: Will it not affect my other part of code?

Comment: `node_modules` is a folder that keeps all your downloaded packages, including `babel` and other that are in your `package.json`. Deleting and runing `npm i` will be like "reinstalling" the packages.

Comment: ok, I will try.

Comment: Check my answer, it will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requires Babel "7.0.0-0" but was loaded with "6.26.3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873516/requires-babel-7-0-0-0-but-was-loaded-with-6-26-3)

Answer (score 2):

You may need the babel 7 bridge as version for `babel-core`

```
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0"
```

in your `package.json`

You can check `package-lock.json` and see what version of `babel-core` is being installed there. If it's still installing `6.26.3`, you may have another package that is requiring that specific version that should be updates as well. In my case it was `jest` as well as `babelify` to the latest versions support `babel 7` to stop it from installing the older babel version in my `package-lock.json`. It does also sound like you do need to update your version of `babel-loader` from that error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` you have this two packages.

```
{
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    ...
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
}
```

[They are the same package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395718/9119186) but the last one is a prior version.

## Edit:

You also need to update `babel-loader`

`"babel-loader": "^8.0.6"`  will work.

Comment: Now, this error is occuring:       ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'

Comment: @Sagar have you runned `npm i` after removing it? Also check the link I added that explains about `@babel/core` and `babel-core`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I actually changed babel-cli to the version 7, so maybe the problem is there