# Installing v6.26.3 of Babel core and cli results in 'No matching version found'

Tags: node.js, npm

### I did this

I tried to install [Babel release 6.26.3](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v6.26.3) with the command `npm install --save-dev @babel/core@6.26.3 @babel/cli@6.26.3` using npm v7.4.3 under node v15.7.0. I got the command from [Using Babel](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation) that suggests `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli` and added the version specifier according to the mend article [npm: How To Install A Specific Version of Node.js Package](https://www.mend.io/free-developer-tools/blog/npm-how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-js-package/) .

When I had these issues I also tried `npm cache clean --force`  before reattempting.

### Happens

The only result I get is `npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/cli@6.26.3`

### Expected

That Babel would install v6.26.3.

Now, if I try too look for available releases with `npm view @babel/core versions,` then I actually don't see any version of 6, except the 6.0.0-bridge.1.

Assuming I don't have syntax issues in the above or that am asking npm for the wrong thing in order to get Babel installed, then is there a way to install v6.26.3 of Babel core and Babel cli? If v6 indeed has been dropped is it perhaps available in some archived repo?

I've done a little bit of Node before, but in the past I haven't had these kind of issues. I'm not familiar with the culture of the platform. Is it common to drop older versions of packages? So the above should be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an explanation from @MichaelDeBoey on why this syntax would fail in the question "[What is the difference between babel-core and @babel/core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395718/427009)?".

So what I needed to do was to instead use this older syntax with `-` and without `@` as package prefix for viewing available versions:

```
npm view babel-core versions
npm view babel-cli versions
```

and likewise install the older versions with the older syntax:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core@6.26.3 babel-cli@6.26.0
```

Note that the view command revealed there was no v6.26.3 version for babel-cli.