# can't run android emulator in command prompt(terminal)

Tags: android, react-native, terminal, android-emulator, yarnpkg

I installed anything for android virtual emulator , and it works in android studio but in terminal when i want to connect my react native project to this emulator i get logs below.
i enter `yarn run android` in terminal.

`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at getCliConfig (C:\Users\mycomputername\project1\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:128:64)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mycomputername\project1\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:181:30)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\mycomputername\project1\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\mycomputername\project1\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`

thank you about reading and maybe answering this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: no my question is about connecting react native to emulator and this link is about another topic. :)