# How to configure .babelrc to support ES6 module imports and async/await?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, babeljs

**Desired Behaviour**

I am trying to import code from one file into another with:

*lib.js*

```
// generate unique id
export const guid = () => {
    const s4 = () => {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
        s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

// get current date as ISO string  
export const currentDateTimeISOString = () => {
    var iso_string = new Date().toISOString();
    return iso_string;
}

// convert boolean string to boolean
export const stringToBoolean = (val) => {
    var a = {
        'true': true,
        'false': false
    };
    return a[val];
}
```

*app_es6.js*

```
import { guid, currentDateTimeISOString, stringToBoolean } from './src/js/lib';
```

**Actual Behaviour**

After build I get the error:

```
export const guid = () => {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

**What I've Tried**

I've googled this error and come across various solutions.

The most up to date approach seems to be:

```
npm install babel-register babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

[source](https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/)

I currently have the following `babel` related dev dependencies in `package.json`:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
```

And `.babelrc` is:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets":
                {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I recently changed `.babelrc` to the above [in order to handle async/await usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010685), it used to be:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

My build script in `package.json` is:

```
"build-server-file": "babel app_es6.js --out-file app.js",
```

I'm concerned about implementing a solution that is outdated or breaks functionality with another part of the codebase (ie, if i revert to my previous version of `.babelrc` then async/await will throw errors).  I've also read that [`stage-x` is depreciated](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0).

**Question**

What is the most up to date way to import/export modules in ES6 in a Node.js environment whilst still supporting the `.babelrc` requirements for async/await?

Comment: Is this being built for the browser? If not, Node on the backend supports ES6 modules since Node 10.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `SyntaxError` is being thrown from within `lib.js` and not `app.js` --this is almost certainly the result of *that* file not being transformed.

The babel command you're using, `babel app_es6.js --out-file app.js` is processing `app_es6.js`; however, `lib.js` is untouched and *that's* likely why you still see ESM `export` syntax when `require()`ing the file.

I set up a minimal gist with updates to what I know about your current setup to make this work the way (I think) you intended: https://gist.github.com/knksmith57/a554defde2d3d7cf64c4f453565352a0

The trick is to **process the entire source directory** and not just your entrypoint file.

### tl;dr:

1. process the entire source directory, **not just the entrypoint**
2. tell `preset-env` to use `cjs` (alias for `commonjs`) as the target module type
3. enable a plugin to transform `async` functions to generator functions (in babel 7.x, that's [`@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator))
4. look at that gist for a complete working example

If you run into trouble backporting my example to babel 6.x, let me know and I can make some time to follow up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The very first line of your answer just helped me resolve hours of debugging...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run a node.js "server".

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/node @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator`

Using the @babel/ namespace will upgrade you from babel 6 to babel 7, the current latest version. The plugin does the async transformation

2. Setup a `.babelrc` or now with 7, especially if you're using node_modules with their own babel configurations, you can use a `babel.config.js` like this:

```js
module.exports = {
      presets: [ '@babel/preset-env'],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator'
      ]
    };
```

3. Update your `package.json` build scripts to something more like this:

```js
 "scripts": {
  "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
  "start": "node dist/app_es6.js"
 }
```

You want to compile your `/lib/` folder into a `/dist/` one. This is the most common pattern you'll see in the community.

As you are looking to make an es6 web-app, I would not recommend actually compiling everything to commonjs (cjs), as that will break webpack (via the babel-loader) from performing tree-shaking. It only works when you use `import/exports` and setting babel to `cjs` instead of the default `ems` will make everything `require/module.exports`.

Answer (score 0):

which version of node are you using?

you can easily update your `node` to version `>= 10v` to use official ES6 features support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same problem and I fix it by a babel plugin that name is `transform-runtime`, and my `.babelrc` the file became like below:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "react",
    "env",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "helpers": true,
        "polyfill": true,
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "compact": false
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about this plugin read [this link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime).