# How to take screen shot of a particular html div element in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my web-application i want to allow user to choose from list of different style signature.When ever user chooses one signature style i want to take picture of the signature style and save it in server. I have tried using canvas2html library it don't seem to work.

I have searched for vue-libaries that can take picture of particular element however there are only screenshot of whole web page.

```
mounted() {
    // Element might not have been added to the DOM yet
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        // Element has been definitely added to the DOM
        // is there any way to acces the div element via el element???
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('container')).
        then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       });
       console.log(this.$el.textContent); // I'm text inside the component.
        });
      }
```

Comment: What is the actual issue?  That code works fine to copy the container element and recreate it on a canvas.

Comment: i have tried using https://github.com/mycure-inc/vue-html2canvas this library. whenever i add import VueHtml2Canvas from 'vue-html2canvas';

Vue.use(VueHtml2Canvas);                                                                                                                         -----------------This results in this error in webpack----------------------------Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I try `html2canvas` library and it seems work fine.

First make sure you already install the library:

```
npm install html2canvas
```

And in component:

```
async mounted () {
  let el = this.$refs.hello.$el; // You have to call $el if your ref is Vue component
  this.output = (await html2canvas(el)).toDataURL();
}
```

[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/302yn4k00p)

If you already using `vue-html2canvas`, you can do like:

```
async mounted() {
  let el = this.$refs.hello.$el;
  let options = { type: "dataURL" };
  this.output = await this.$html2canvas(el, options);
}
```

[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/z604wm3zmm)

Note: It seems `vue-html2canvas` has a problem with babel, see [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined) for how to fix it (in my example I simply import "regenerator-runtime/runtime").

Comment: Thank you!!! https://codesandbox.io/s/r7n9qmlxmo is working for me.                 
    async mounted () {
    let el = this.$refs.hello.$el;
    console.log(this.$refs+"i am refs value")
    console.log(el+"i am el value")
  }                                                                                                                                             can you tell me why we are using async mount lifecycle hook. I have multiple signatures from which user can choose from so i will have multiple refs. when ever i access one ref from multiple refs. the ref give me undefined.

Comment: I use `async mount` only for example. I create https://codesandbox.io/s/31z1vj7815 that based on user click. The $ref could be undefined because of that moment the element is not render yet (maybe because of condition rendering like v-if).