# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for import _regeneratorRuntime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, babeljs

I'm following the [React setup guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project) for setting up React for the first time.  However, I've added async/await to my code.  When the preprocessor - `npx babel` runs, the output file looks like:

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError]

and the browser console is giving me the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

for the import.

I've checked that `babel-runtime` is in my node-modules.

My `package.json` dependencies looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

Comment: what is in `.babelrc`?

Comment: I don't have a `.babelrc` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: I installed the devDependencies from there and added the `.babelrc` file.  Now the import changed to `var _regenerator = require('babel-runtime/regenerator');` and I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Hmm, now Node-specific problem with `require`. I think its a known issue. will check. but I think better to stick to Es6 `import`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, remove the old dependencies

```
npm uninstall -D babel-cli babel-preset-react-app babel-runtime
```

then add the latest dependencies

```
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/preset-react @babel/cli babel-runtime
```

after the latest dependencies installed `package.json` looks like

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    ...
```

after fixing this you might face an issue(`regeneratorRuntime is not defined`) then you need to add the `runtime.js` script in your HTML file

https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/blob/master/packages/runtime/runtime.js