# ReferenceError regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm building an SSR template, and when I use @babebl/register and then execute webpack (config), the system reported an error.
I tried @babel/polyfill and @babel/plugin-transform-runtime, but none of them worked.

Babel version(s): 7.4.3
Node/npm version: [e.g. Node 10.15.3/npm 6.4.1]
OS: window 10

`index.js:`

```
require("ignore-styles");
require("@babel/register")({
  ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import", "dynamic-import-node"]
});
require("./server");
```

`server.js`

```
const config = require('../config/webpack.dev.config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const express = require('express')
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware') 
const reactRouter = require('react-router')
const StaticRouter = reactRouter.reactRouter;
const app = express()
const complier = webpack(config)
const PORT = 8090
...
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(complier, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}))

app.listen(PORT , function() {
  console.log(`SSR running on port ${PORT }`);
})
```

`webpack.dev.config.js`

```
const paths = require('./paths')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', paths.appIndexJs],
  output: {
    path: paths.clientBuild,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: paths.publicPath
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', { 
              useBuiltIns: 'usage', 
              corejs: "2",  
              targets: {
                  browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9'],
              },
            }],
            '@babel/preset-react'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './client/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

[image]

#### Rep

https://github.com/xuchenchenBoy/ssr （Please execute npm run dev:server and release notes in server.js）

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: there are many, many questions on Stack Overflow which deal with this exact error. Which of them have you researched, which solutions have you attempted, and why were they not successful?

Comment: @DanO I tried those methods, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @chenxu, have you tried `import "babel-polyfill";`? And since you are doing SSR, you need to add that in both your server-side top level root file and your client-side equivalent. Give that a try and post the code for it on how you did it before you share that the problem still exists.