# Error while trying to run scripts: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, babeljs, chai

I have problem to run a test in mocha and chai. I am getting an error:

> Error while trying to run scripts: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

and 500 status internal error.

I've thought it's some kind of a problem with babel configuration and tested functionalities manually and it's working.

package.json:

```
json


     "scripts": {
            "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require @babel/register --recursive './test/**/*.spec.js'"
          }
```

.babelrc:

```
json

    {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
      ]
    }
```

test:

```
javascript
import chai from "chai";
import server from "../../index";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
const { expect } = chai;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

function validResponse(err, res, status) {
  expect(err).to.be.null;
  expect(res).to.have.status(status);
  expect(res).to.be.json;
}

describe("get one page of recipe", function() {

  it("should return page with recipe", function(done) {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .get("/api/recipe/page/1")
      .end((err, res) => {
        validResponse(err, res, 200);
        console.log(res.body)
        expect(res.body).to.be.an("object");
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you are using a feature that's not supported properly by the Babel presets configured.

Try installing `babel-polyfill`,

```
npm i -D babel-polyfill
```

And then include it in your startup file,

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Comment: Ok, but i am using es6 not es5, is it important or no ?

Comment: Do you know any tutorial that teach me how to use mocha, chai and configure it with ES6 ?

Comment: @KursGoogle It also downloads other peer dependencies that could help solve your issue. Try it and let me know if it works. And about the tutorial, I learnt from Pluralsight.

Comment: Can you look at question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340270/expressjs-doesnt-fires-next-routes-in-app-use also ?

Comment: No wait. I accept it too quick. Still the same error.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, working but with import 'babel-polyfill'; - you can edit your post for next people ?