# ExpressJS doesn't fires next routes in app.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem that ExpressJS fires wrong routes while using app.use
This is the code from index.js file, where i combine all routes:

```
const app = express(),
  Router = express.Router();

app.use("/api/vehicle", vehiclesRoutes(Router));
app.use("/api/static-costs", staticCostsRoutes(Router));
app.use("/api/company", companiesRoutes(Router));
app.use("/api/worker", workersRoutes(Router));
```

Each of this functions (vehiclesRoutes, staticCostsRoutes etc.) are constructed the same.

For example vehicleRoutes:

```
export default (router) => {
  router.get("/:company_id", getVehiclesByCompany);
  router.post("/:company_id", postVehicle);
  router.put("/:company_id/:id", putVehicle);
  router.delete("/:company_id/:id", deleteVehicle);
  return router;
};
```

For example staticCostsRoutes:

```
export default router => {
  router.get("/:company_id", getStaticCostsByCompany);
  router.post("/:company_id", postStaticCost);
  router.put("/:company_id/:id", putStaticCost);
  router.delete("/:company_id/:id", deleteStaticCost);
  return router;
};
```

I am passing Express Router, pinning routes and return Router.

When i am trying to call **PUT /api/static-cost/:company_id/:id**,
it fires **PUT /api/vehicles/:company_id/:id**.

I mentioned something interesting, when i exchange these two things:

```
app.use("/api/static-costs", staticCostsRoutes(Router));
app.use("/api/vehicle", vehiclesRoutes(Router));
```

The situation is reverse, when i am trying to call **PUT /api/vehicle/:company_id/:id**,it fires **PUT /api/static-costs/:company_id/:id**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You are creating the `Router` object and passing the same reference to all the methods.
If you closely observe in all the methods the routes are the same, only the controllers differ.

So, in this case, the commonly referenced `Router` passed to `vehicleRoutes(Router)` function registers the `getVehiclesByCompany` controller to the GET `/:company_id` route. And then the following attempts to register `getStaticCostsByCompany` controller at the same route in `staticCostsRoutes(Router)` function is ignored.

**Solution**

Instead of creating `Router` and passing the same reference to all the functions.
Create a new `Router` object within each of the functions and return it so that they don't share the same reference.

```
const app = express(),

app.use("/api/vehicle", vehiclesRoutes());
app.use("/api/static-costs", staticCostsRoutes());
app.use("/api/company", companiesRoutes());
app.use("/api/worker", workersRoutes());
```

vehicleRoutes.js

```
const router = express.Router();
export default () => {
  router.get("/:company_id", getVehiclesByCompany);
  router.post("/:company_id", postVehicle);
  router.put("/:company_id/:id", putVehicle);
  router.delete("/:company_id/:id", deleteVehicle);
  return router;
};
```

staticCostsRoutes.js

```
const router = express.Router();
export default () => {
  router.get("/:company_id", getStaticCostsByCompany);
  router.post("/:company_id", postStaticCost);
  router.put("/:company_id/:id", putStaticCost);
  router.delete("/:company_id/:id", deleteStaticCost);
  return router;
};
```