# Rollup fails to transpile async/await - regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, babeljs, rollupjs

I want to use async/await with rollup.

I tried searching for babel and rollup issues on stackoverflow and github and nothing resolved my issue.

`@babel/runtime/regenerator` is being treated as an external dependency.  I see a console error: `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.  Before you ask, yes I did look at every other post with this topic and none of the ones I could find solved this issue.

I've tried using @babel/polyfill even though it's deprecated and people say not to use it.  I've tried `import`ing it before my main imports, I've tried importing `transform-runtime`, nothing I do works.

*Compile warning:*

```
src/main.js → dist/bundle.js...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
@babel/runtime/regenerator (imported by src/cronreader.js, src/animations.js)
created dist/bundle.js in 549ms
```

*rollup.config.js:*

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import async from 'rollup-plugin-async';

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'iife',
        globals: {
            "@babel/runtime/regenerator": "regeneratorRuntime",
            "@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator": "asyncToGenerator"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        async(),
        resolve({
            customResolveOptions: {
                moduleDirectory: 'src'
            }
        }),
        babel({
            runtimeHelpers: true,
            exclude: 'node_modules/**', // only transpile our source code
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: [
                "@babel/transform-runtime",
                "@babel/transform-regenerator",
                "@babel/transform-async-to-generator",
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```

*package.json:*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@node-minify/cli": "^4.1.2",
    "@node-minify/crass": "^4.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "node-minify": "^3.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rollup": "^1.18.0",
    "rollup-plugin-async": "^1.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "uglify-js": "^3.6.0"
  },
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"
}
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "@babel/runtime"
  ]
```

There is no .babelrc file.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with getting this to work with rollup and babel. I also tried the `transform-runtime` and other plugins, all to no avail.

```[
  {
    plugins: [
      babel({
        babelrc: false,
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              corejs: 3,
              modules: false,
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
              targets: {
                ie: '11',
              },
            },
          ],
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you already solved the issue, but just for a future reference, this answer did it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821986/839273

I just installed transform-runtime with `npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, enabled runtimeHelpers in rollup.config.js like you have it above and then just added

```
["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
   "regenerator": true
}]
```

to plugins node inside .babelrc -> just for clarity this is my complete .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-inline-json-import",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Newb Q - Do we need both .babelrc and the entry we add into rollup.config.js?

Comment: It's quite a long time ago, so I don't remember much of it already, but I'd say yes. Both together did the job for me