# babel doesn't parse async await

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I'm updating an old react app where its webpack config uses babel loader and its babelrc uses

```
"presets": ["react", "es2015"],
```

the error I get with a new file that uses async await is

```
[dev:server] SyntaxError: src/views/pages/V2.js: Unexpected token (25:13)
[dev:server]   23 |   }
[dev:server]   24 | 
[dev:server] > 25 |   updateUser = async () => {
[dev:server]      |              ^
```

I've installed babel-preset-es2017 as well as babel-preset-env and updated the presets in the babelrc but still gives that error

is it missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the same problem with installing *"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",* and adding it to .babelrc file.

```
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
...
],
```

*Check this out on: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime*

I've also found another option on my other project:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
        ],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

**Just found probably duplicate issue, take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)**

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is part of es2017.
You might want to consider using babel-preset-es2017 instead, [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2017/).