# Reactjs - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel-loader

After deleting the node module and yarn.lock I run `yarn install` and I dont know why i received this error, please help. Thanks

I used react js for this one.

```
./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 2119:34
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2119:34)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js  
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|           async destroy() {
|             this.destroyed = true;
>             await this._transport?.destroy();
|             this._transport = null;
|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders

Comment: @AymenHammami No

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to add async/await parsing support in babel.

Try this in your babel config file:

```
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
...
],
```

Ref:

> [babel doesn't parse async await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450670/babel-doesnt-parse-async-await)

Comment: what file should I apply this?

Comment: Babel config file, check out this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files

Answer (score -2):

Try using the newest version of pdfjs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).