# Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime when using Sync/Await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when using Async/Await for functions:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime
```

Seems to be a common problem but I've tried a couple of solutions I found on stackoverflow to no avail, I've now ended up with a huge list of babel dependencies. :) I'm very confused about all this, could someone spot what's wrong with my babel/webpack files?

Thank you

Package.json (relevant dependencies only)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    [
      "env"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    entry: ["./src/index"],
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 20000
                        }
                    },
                    "image-webpack-loader"
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: true,
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
    ], 
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }
};


module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: @aRvi First thing that popped up for me. I've tried many of the solutions but only ended up with more errors, all of this is very overwhelming for me.

Answer (score 0):

I took the config files you've provided and did a small test - https://codesandbox.io/s/async-await-webpack-ljv7h?file=/src/App.js I don't see anything wrong with it. I was able to use async/await just fine. May be try a clean up and reinstall - `rm package-lock.json && rm -rm node_modules && npm install` and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the plugin

.babelrc

```
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
```

in my case I always do this:

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack webpack-cli
```

I also suggest you use:

.babelrc

```
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
```

and if you are using react you may also need preset "@babel/preset-react"

```
"presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
```