# React custom utility function seeing Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have the following code in my React App component, where I am trying to get some JSON and want to send that to my custom hook.

```
const fetchFn = useCommonFetch();
const [user1, status1] = fetchFn('myapi/urls', {}, 'GET');

useEffect(() => {
    someCustomHookCall(user1); // Pass "user1" JSON info to someCustomHookCall
}, [user1])
```

Below is how the useCommonFetch looks;

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function useCommonFetch() {
    const fetchData = async (url, reqData, requestType) => {
        try {
            var statusObj = {
                statMsg: null,
                errMsg: null,
                status: null,
            };
            var reqOptions = {
                credentials: 'same-origin'
            }
            if (requestType === 'POST') {
                reqOptions.headers = {};
                reqOptions.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
                reqOptions.method = 'POST';
                reqOptions.body = JSON.stringify(reqData);
            }
            const response = await fetch(url, reqOptions);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw response;
            }
            statusObj.status = "success";
            const json = await response.json();
            return [json, statusObj];
        } catch (error) {
            statusObj.status = "error";
            if (error && error.status) {
                switch (error.status) {
                    case 401:
                        statusObj.errMsg = "Unauthorized";
                        console.error("Unauthorized: " + error.status);
                        break;
                    default:
                        statusObj.errMsg = "Sys error";
                }
            }
            return [null, statusObj];
        }

    }
    return fetchData;
}
```

I am getting the following error while running

> Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

Not sure what is wrong in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you're trying to destructure a pending promise.
I have created a short [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-dew-txf8dj?file=/src/App.js) that suggests another way of achieving your expectation, but something causes the component to re-render nonstop.

Comment: This appears to be a link to an answer rather than an answer in and of itself. Stack Overflow works better when users don't have to navigate to another site to see the answer to their question.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchFn` is an asynchronous function and it returns a promise(and not an array), I suggest you change the `useCommonFetch` as follows:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const fetchData = async (url, reqData, requestType) => {
  ...
}

export default function useCommonFetch(url, reqData, requestType) {
    const [state, setState] = useState([null, null]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function getData() {
        const result = await fetchData(url, reqData, requestType);
        setState(result);
      }
      getData();
    }, [url, reqData, requestType])

    return state;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
const [user1, status1] = useCommonFetch('myapi/urls', null, 'GET');

useEffect(() => {
  if(user1) {
    someCustomHookCall(user1); // Pass "user1" JSON info to someCustomHookCall
  }
}, [user1])
```

[image: Edit vibrant-joliot-5yvg9r]

Comment: Thanks a lot for that....Not sure but seeing Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined probably for the line const fetchData = async (url, reqData, requestType) => {

Comment: Check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined), I also added an online example

Comment: Thanks again...On the CodeSandbox link...for some reason, getting err: 
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: That's strange, I checked again and it worked