# How to properly import THREE js library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, three.js, node-modules

I installed the *three* library via npm. In the *node_modules* directory there is the *three* folder. But when I wanted to import it using:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

it gives the following error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
> ```

But when I use;

```js
import * as THREE from 'three/build/three.cjs';
```

it properly works. Also, the same problem occurs while importing external plugins:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three.js uses ES6 async/await, you need to upgrade or configure your babel presets to support async/await.
This may help
[Babel 6 regeneratorRuntime is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks, I used this answer, it fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759820/8110756

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you reference the correct path where your *three.module* is.
I'd try the following for a script being in the `rootForlder/src/theScriptWhereYourImportIs.js`:

```js
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
```

If the script is at the same hierarchy level as your *node_modules* folder then the following should work:

```js
import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
```

As far as I remember I had to make some trials and figure this out as it was not very clear in the documentation. Any insight will be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759820/8110756