# Javascript 2D array getting each element

Tags: javascript, for-loop, chart.js

I have a 2D array that looks like:

```
var example = [['Version', 'Number'], [ 'V1.0', 1 ], [ 'V2.0', 2 ]];
```

I'd like to iterate through the array and take out 'V1.0' and 'V2.0' and store them in their own new array, and do the same for '1' and '2'.  I need to break the data up for use with Chart.js

My loop looks like this:

```
var labels = [];
var data = [];

for (var i=0; i<example.length; i++) {
    labels.push = (example[i][0]);
}

for (var j=0; j<example.length; j++) {
    data.push = (example[0][j]);
}
```

I don't know how to properly get either element into their own array for use later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop in multidimensional javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021847/for-loop-in-multidimensional-javascript-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do this, and [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) the result in order to remove the first occurence.

```js
var example = [
  ['Version', 'Number'],
  ['V1.0', 1],
  ['V2.0', 2]
];

var result = example.map(e => e[0])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw into your example the first pair of elements are the keys for your data, into your example will include them into your final arrays.

This example will generate to a dictionary with the keys Number and Version containing the corresponding values from your array.

```js
var example = [['Version', 'Number'], [ 'V1.0', 1 ], [ 'V2.0', 2 ]];

function extract(items) {
  var keys = {},
      version = items[0][0],
      number = items[0][1];
  
  keys[version] = [];
  keys[number] = [];
   
  return items.slice(1).reduce(function(acc, item) {
    acc[version].push(item[0]);    
    acc[number].push(item[1]);
    
    return acc;
  }, keys);
}

var result = extract(example);
console.log(result);
```

From this point you can do something like:

```
var labels = result.Version;
var data = result.Number;
```

Comment: I like this answer.  I gave the one above the accepted answer because its simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are trying to achieve:

```
for(var i=0; i<example.length; i++){

  labels.push(example[i][0])
  data.push(example[i][1])
}
```