# Why do we use [Symbol.iterator] instead of a `for` loop?

Tags: javascript, iterator, symbols

I'm reading [Eloquent JavaScript's "The Iterator Interface" section](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) and I have trouble understanding why we need to define `MatrixIterator` function to iterate `Matrix`'s contents. I usually use `for` inside of another `for` to iterate the contents of a two-dimensional matrix, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021847/for-loop-in-multidimensional-javascript-array). Is it because the `[Symbol.iterator]`'s of each object in JS is used whenever you call the shorthand of `for` loop which is `for...of`?

Furthermore, am I correct to assume that the standard `[Symbol.iterator]` cannot automatically iterate a two-dimensional objects and thus, the need to create `MatrixIterator` and assigning it as:

```
Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};
```

Are we allowed to do this instead: `Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = MatrixIterator;`?

Off-topic: I feel like I should know some other things more in-depth as I feel rather confused about these concepts. Could someone also elaborate what interface means? The book did mention it as:

> Different pieces of such a program interact with each other through interfaces, limited sets of functions or bindings that provide useful functionality at a more abstract level, hiding their precise implementation.

and

> Separating interface from implementation is a great idea. It is usually called encapsulation.

but it did not mention what implementation is.

Comment: Voted to close because this is 3-4 questions at once... First, yes, a `for` loop does not know how to iterate on a `Matrix`, so you need a custom `Symbol.iterator`.  This is kind of a silly toy example though, usually with matrices you want to multiply or do other operations on the whole matrix.

Comment: Are we allowed to do this instead: `Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = MatrixIterator` - This won't work because the `MatrixIterator` no longer has a reference to the matrix object (the `this` in `new MatrixIterator(this)`).  It might be possible to write `MatrixIterator` in a way so that this can work, but it wouldn't be as clean or as useful code.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation! @jnylen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the shorthand of `for` loop which is `for...of`?

No, `for … of` is not a shorthand for a normal `for (…; …; …)` loop. It's a completely separate mechanism.

> Why do we need to define `MatrixIterator` function to iterate `Matrix`'s contents?. Is it because the `[Symbol.iterator]`'s of each object in JS is used whenever you use `for...of`?

Yes. We define the `MatrixIterator` as it conforms to the iterator interface, as is expected to be returned by a `Symbol.iterator` method to be usable in such a loop.

Of course there are alternative ways to achieve this, we don't necessarily need to make an extra `MatrixIterator` class. A generator function is usually the easiest.

> I usually use `for` inside of another `for` to iterate the contents of a two-dimensional matrix

Sure, but that's quite some syntactic overhead - two loops, two counters, double indentation. It could be much simpler, and we don't want to repeat this pattern everywhere when we want to iterate a matrix. The iterable interface allows this.

> am I correct to assume that the standard `[Symbol.iterator]` cannot automatically iterate a two-dimensional objects

There is no standard `Symbol.iterator` method. Every type needs to define it itself. `Array.prototype` does, for example, but it works only on arrays not on our `Matrix` class.

> Are we allowed to do this instead: `Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = MatrixIterator;`?

That doesn't work, as `MatrixIterator` a) is a constructor that needs to be invoked with `new` b) takes the matrix instance that it should iterate as an argument

Comment: I see, thank you for the answers. I think that I'm missing a lot of things I should've known by this point, do you think so too? If so, what should I read or focus on?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer No idea, I think "Eloquent JavaScript"s curriculum is just fine. (At least that of the first edition seemed reasonable, I didn't read the second one)