# Loop Through Nested Array Elements With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm trying to loop through nested arrays to determine if an element in the array is either "open" or "senior":

```
function openOrSenior(data) {

  for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {

    let dataElement = data[i];

    for (let j = 0; j <= dataElement.length; j++) {

      if (dataElement[0] >= 55 && dataElement[1] > 7) {

        return ["Senior"];

      }

      return ["Open"];

    }
  }
}
```

Given the input of

`[[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]`

The function should output

`["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]`

But currently it looks like it's only looping through the first element in the main array (`[18, 20]`) because my function is only returning:

`["Open"]`

Why is this function failing to continue to loop through the other nested arrays and return either "Open" or "Senior"? Possibly a problem with the scope?

https://www.codewars.com/kata/categorize-new-member/train/javascript

I was trying to implement what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021847/for-loop-in-multidimensional-javascript-array), which suggested a for-loop within a for-loop.

Comment: Why do you need the second loop? There are only two elements in `dataElement` and you are mentioning them by index, so why the second loop?

Comment: Oh yes, true - removing the second for-loop still returns, `[Open]`, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning whenever the check succeeds or not, and you've got a redundant for loop. You should iterate the array with a single for loop, and according to the check push Senior or Open to the `result` array. In the end return the `result` array.

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const dataElement = data[i];

    if (dataElement[0] >= 55 && dataElement[1] > 7) {
      result.push("Senior");
    } else result.push("Open");
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(openOrSenior([[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]));
```

Or you can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const openOrSenior = data => 
  data.map(([a, b]) => 
    a >= 55 && b > 7 ? 'Senior' : 'Open'
  )

console.log(openOrSenior([[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need only a single loop and an array for the values.

```js
function openOrSenior(data) {
    var result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let [left, right] = data[i];
        result.push(left >= 55 && right > 7
            ? "Senior"
            : "Open"
        );
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(openOrSenior([[18, 20], [45, 2], [61, 12], [37, 6], [21, 21], [78, 9]]));
```