# iterate through all permutations of two variables

Tags: javascript

I need to call the following function `cross` 4 times, for all permutations of the `x` and `y` variable with the values 1 and -1;

my approach:

```
var p = [-1, 1];

p.forEach(function(x) {
  p.forEach(function(y) {
    cross(x, y);
  });
});
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: I think there's an algorithm to produce n^2 combinations that is more efficient than n^2.

Comment: By shorter do you mean in lines of code or in time (more efficient)?

Comment: both would be interesting.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as finding all permutations of elements in Javascript arrays [already has an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript).

Comment: @alex: In fact he's not looking for permutations, but for the [cartesian product](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15298912/1048572) of that array.

Comment: Are you looking for a general permutation/combination algorithm, either DFS or BFS?

Comment: thats pretty fast.  Running 1million time generally takes ~620ms.  http://jsfiddle.net/1zbrshsd/

Comment: @Rooster depends on browser

Comment: for gereneric array cross product see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/1715004

Comment: @FilipeBorges good point.  but my general point still holds true.  its fast enough that the need for a faster solution is negligible.  But its always fun to try to squeeze it out if you have the time available.  :)

Comment: @alex This would likely be considered 'example code' and closed as off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg +1 [fair enough](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be extra functional, you can use `map` and then `reduce` the arrays into one. I don't think it would necessarily be any more efficient than what you have now, nor is it much simpler (it is more functional, just slightly).

```js
var d = [-1, 1];

var r = d.reduce(function(p, x) {
  return p.concat(d.map(function(y) {
    return cross(x, y);
  }));
}, []);

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(r);
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

I really don't think there is an algorithm with better than n^2 efficiency to produce n^2 combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the length of your array p you don't need a loop. The fastest solution would be:

```
var p = [-1, 1];
cross(p[0], p[0]);
cross(p[0], p[1]);
cross(p[1], p[0]);
cross(p[1], p[1]);
```

Comment: this is the most obvious solution for the specific case, upvoted!

Comment: why are you using `0` instead of `-1`?

Comment: @naomik: it's position 0, not value 0

Comment: Hey, the array is static, so it would be even faster not accessing it at all and doing `cross(-1, -1); cross(-1, 1); cross(1, -1); cross(1, 1);` :-)

Comment: That would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is some overhead in calling a function. e.g. putting the return pointer on the stack. It would probably be slightly faster to use two for loops rather than callbacks to forEach.

```
var p = [-1, 1];
for (var x = 0; x < p.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < p.length; y++) {
        cross(p[x], p[y]);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be faster:

```
for (var n = 0; n < 4; ++n) 
     cross(n & 2 ? 1:-1, n & 1 ? -1:1);
```

but is it shorter?