# Translating an array comprehension to `map` and `filter`

Tags: javascript, arrays, list-comprehension

Array comprehensions are a feature of Firefox (Gecko) that is not standard, and the Mozilla documentation itself recommends usage of `map` and `filter` instead.

Can you convert the following array comprehension to a combination of `map` and `filter`?

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var letters = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ];

var cross = [for (i of numbers) 
             for (j of letters) 
             if (i % 2 == 0) i+j];
```

Expected result:

```
[ '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e' ]
```

Comment: I try to understand. What should be the result?

Comment: You need the even or the odd keys?

Comment: Added expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is first obtain the Cartesian product then you can filter and map the resulting array.

## Python

```python
from itertools import product

numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

cross = map(lambda x:'{0}{1}'.format(*x),filter(lambda e:e[0]%2==0,product(numbers,letters)))

print cross # ['2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e']
```

## JavaScript

```js
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310051/1762224
function cartesian() {
  var r = [], args = arguments, max = args.length - 1;
  function helper(arr, i) {
    for (var j = 0, l = args[i].length; j < l; j++) {
      var a = arr.slice(0).concat(args[i][j]); // Clone arr
      if (i === max) { r.push(a); }
      else { helper(a, i + 1); }
    }
  }
  helper([], 0);
  return r;
}

var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ];

var cross = cartesian(numbers, letters)
          . filter(function(item, index, arr) { return item[0] % 2 === 0; })
          . map(function(item, index, arr)    { return item.join(''); });

console.log(cross); // [ '2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e' ]
```

---

## More Efficient Design

As Andy suggested in the comments, you could filter the `numbers` array ahead-of-time so that you do not need to create such a large product.

```
var cross = cartesian(
        numbers.filter(function(number) {
            return number % 2 === 0;
        }),
        letters)
    .map(function(item) {
        return item.join('');
    });
```

Comment: You are onto something, but the code should use a `permutation` function, not a `zip` one.  I have added the expected result to my snippet.

Comment: @Elena: I was confused, until you included desired output. I updated my answer. I hope it is the intended result.

Comment: Why not just filter out the even numbers and iterate over those? Less painless

Comment: @Andy: You could do that, but what I provided was a *general* Cartesian product function. Either way, I provided an example of what you requested. Of course you could tailor your own custom function to handle two arrays, but a general *Cartesian Product* function would be desirable;helpful to most people.

Answer (score 0):

This answer also uses `reduce` to flatten the output:

```
function comp(numbers, letter) {

  // filter out the even numbers
  return numbers.filter(function (number) {
    return number % 2 === 0;
  }).map(function (number) {

    // for each letter append the number that we're currently
    // iterating (from map)
    return letters.map(function (letter) {
      return number + letter;
    });

  // use reduce and concat to flatten the output of two nested
  // arrays into one array
  }).reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p.concat(c);
  });
}

comp(numbers, letters); // [ "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "4a", "4b", "4c", "4d", "4e" ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3jjbmae4/)