# Use Javascript array and loops to display all 216 websafe colors in hexadecimal on a page

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need to create a JavaScript function that uses an array to hold the values: `["00", "33", "66", "99", "CC", "FF"]`. I then need to loop through the array and display all 216 web safe colors as hexadecimal values on my page. The code below is what I have so far but I am not sure about looping through to create the rest of the numbers.

```
function displayColors() {
    var hex1;
    var hex2;
    var hex3;
    var clr;
    var steps = [
        '00',
        '33',
        '66',
        '99',
        'cc',
        'ff' 
    ];
    var arrLength = steps.length;
    var counter = 1; // Make sure there are 216 colors displayed

        for (var b = 0; b < arrLength; b++) {
            hex1 = steps[b];
            hex2 = steps[b];
            hex3 = steps[b];
            clr = hex1 + hex2 + hex3;
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += 
                "<div>" + counter + ": " + clr + "</div>";
            counter++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you want to display every combination of these elements from array?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: One color have 6 characters?

Comment: Yes it would be 6 characters for example output would be "000000", "000033", "000066", etc

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this:

```
 for (var a = 0; a < arrLength; a++) {
        for (var b = 0; b < arrLength; b++) {
            for (var c = 0; c < arrLength; c++) {
                hex1 = steps[a];
                hex2 = steps[b];
                hex3 = steps[c];
                clr = hex1 + hex2 + hex3;
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += "<div>" + counter + ": " + clr + "</div>";
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. However I am not sure exactly how it works out?

Comment: When it was a single loop you were just moving along the same index of the array for each color ff ff ff, 00 00 00, etc,  What you needed was to be able to step through each index independently for each of the 3 places hence 3 for loops

Answer (score 1):

This is the loop that you need:

Here's the fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/6xtdjku4/)

```
var steps = ['00', '33', '66', '99', 'cc', 'ff'];
for(var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < steps.length; j++){
    for(var k = 0; k < steps.length; k++){
        console.log(steps[i] + steps[j] + steps[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be fun to name the variables `r`, `g`, `b`.

Comment: Yes! I noticed that

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using your array, have a look at [Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310051/1048572) - which you could use as `cartesian(steps, steps, steps).map(parts => parts.join(""))`.

However, there's a much easier way than to deal with hex string arrays. Use plain numbers:

```
for (var r=0; r<=0xFF0000; r+=0x330000)
    for (var g=0; g<=0xFF00; g+=0x3300)
        for (var b=0; b<=0xFF; b+=0x33)
            console.log( (r|g|b).toString(16).padStart(6, "0") );
```