# Get distinct n-tuples from multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a multi-dimensional array storing groups of N as below. From each group I need to get a distinct N-tuple, as shown in the example. I may not know in advance the size of the group.

I started creating nested for-loops (with the intention to add it to a Set to avoid duplicates) but somehow I'm drawing a blank on this one. Is there a scalable algorithm, or a JS Set I can use here? Would JS even allow you to implement a custom Object Set with its own equals() like Java?

I need to solve this problem in JavaScript, but in theory it's an algorithm question.

```js
var array = [
              [
                ["abc", "def"],
                ["123", "456", "789"],
                ["-", "--"]
              ],
              
              [
                ["X"], 
                ["0", "1", "2"]
              ]
            ];
            
 /* Expected result after processing:
 
    ["abc", "123", "-"],
    ["abc", "123", "--"],
    ["abc", "456", "-"],
    ["abc", "456", "--"],
    ["abc", "789", "-"],
    ["abc", "789", "--"],
    ["def", "123", "-"],
    ["def", "123", "--"],
    ["def", "456", "-"],
    ["def", "456", "--"],
    ["def", "789", "-"],
    ["def", "789", "--"],
    // Next element
    ["X", "0"],
    ["X", "1"],
    ["X", "2"]
*/

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++) {  // May not exist
       // ??
    }
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So... [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript) ?

Comment: [`array.concatMap(cartesian)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310051/1048572)?

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks guys

Comment: Bergi's ref seems a bit more robust (the first one does not seem to flatten elements that are arrays themselves)