# Find all permutations of 2 arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to find every permutations of 2 arrays like this:

```
// input
lowerWords = ['one', 'two', 'three' ] 
upperWords = [ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]

// output
keywords = {
  'one two three': true,
  'ONE two three': true,
  'ONE TWO three': true,
  'ONE TWO THREE': true,
  'ONE two THREE': true,
  'one TWO three': true,
  'one two THREE': true,
  'one TWO THREE': true,
}
```

It should function with more than 3 items, both arrays will always be same length. This is my code:

```
const keywords = {}
const lowerWords = ['one', 'two', 'three' ] 
const upperWords = [ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]
const wordCount = lowerWords.length

let currentWord = 0
let currentWords = [...upperWords]
while (currentWord < wordCount) {
  currentWords[currentWord] = lowerWords[currentWord]
  let keyword = currentWords.join(' ')
  keywords[keyword] = true
  currentWord++
}

currentWord = 0
currentWords = [...lowerWords]
while (currentWord < wordCount) {
  currentWords[currentWord] = upperWords[currentWord]
  let keyword = currentWords.join(' ')
  keywords[keyword] = true
  currentWord++
}
```

result is missing some

```
ONE TWO THREE: true
ONE TWO three: true
ONE two three: true
one TWO THREE: true
one two THREE: true
one two three: true
```

Comment: in your desired answer 3rd and 9th are repeating.

Comment: @Tigger no, those are combinations of 2, I need permutation of every item

Comment: @JackOfAshes-MohitGawande yes that's a mistake

Comment: You are not looking for permutations (which are about order), but for the [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298912/1048572) of `[one, ONE]`, `[two, TWO]` and `[three, THREE]`. You can get those by transposing your input.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure if your suggestion generalises to arbitrary input (see my comment under Nina Scholz's answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could transpose the arrays for getting an array of pairs and then get all combinations of the pairs.

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    combinations = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

var lowerWords = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    upperWords = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'],
    pairs = transpose([lowerWords, upperWords]),
    result = combinations(pairs);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: (This fails for the general version with `transpose([['ONE','TWO','THREE'],['one','two'], [1,2,3,4]])` compare with [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264734/2034787).)

Comment: `transpose` transposes same length arrays.

Comment: @גלעדברקן It's unclear what output you'd want to get from that input anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I implemented one such clarity.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Well, with the transposed input format this really doesn't make sense. One should just call `cartesian([['one', 'ONE', 1], ['two','TWO', 2], ['three', 3], [4]])` if that kind of output is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd give it a try. I used binary to get the possible combinations, as this problem needed a base 2 solution:

```js
const low = ["one", "two", "three"];
const up = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"];

const words = [low, up]
const len = words[0].length


function getCombinations(noOfArrays, len) {
  var temp, newCombo, combos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (noOfArrays ** len); i++) {
    temp = new Array(len).fill(0)
    newCombo = i.toString(noOfArrays).split('');
    newCombo.forEach((el, i) => temp[temp.length - newCombo.length + i] = +el);
    combos.push(temp);
  }
  return combos;
}

function setCombinations(combos) {
  return combos.map(combo => combo.map((el, i) => words[el][i]))
}


var combos = getCombinations(words.length, len)
combos = setCombinations(combos)


console.log(combos)
```

Explanation of loop:

```
1. temp = new Array(len).fill(0)
2. newCombo = i.toString(2).split("");
3. newCombo.forEach((el, i) => temp[temp.length - newCombo.length + i] = +el);
```

1. Creates temp array `[0,0,0]`
2. Grabs loop number (i) and converts it to binary e.g:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 10
3 -> 11
4 -> 100
etc...
```

Then split the binary into an array `100 -> [1,0,0]`.

3. Then for each element push it in that new array. This gave a problem with pushing the 1 and 2 element arrays (`10 -> [1,0]`) into the back of the array. I used `temp.length - newCombo.length + i` to fix that.

That function then returns:

```
[ 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 0 ]
[ 0, 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 0, 0 ]
[ 1, 0, 1 ]
[ 1, 1, 0 ]
[ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

Then, I can map over each combination, and grab each array depending on the value, and get the words ('one' or 'ONE') via loop index.

> Note this code works with more than one array, as long as the arrays are all the same length.

Comment: Hi, I had *favorited* this question to come back later to provide an answer. My answer is very similar to yours (I independently came up, I swear :)). I have also added a generic version of it. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @adiga No problem, great minds think alike :p I like this approach because it's very scalable, since you can just change which base you are converting the index to for how many arrays the user provides. I didn't think about using padStart, either, so nicely done 

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a total of 2 ^ 3 combinations. If you create a 2D matrix from the 2 arrays, the below table represents the row number from which of the item should be taken.

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

If you analyze indexes of the combinations, each of this a binary number from 0 to 2 ^ 3 with leading zeros.

So, you could

- loop from 0 to 8
- create binary number using [`toString(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#Parameters)
- Add leading zero using [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)
- `split` each digit to get an array
- Get each item from `matrix[digit-from-binary][position-of-each-split]`
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array of items with a `' '` separator to get the *key*
- Add the key to the output object

**Working snippet:**

```js
function getAllCombinations(matrix) {
  const combinations = 2 ** 3,
        output = {};
  
  for(let i = 0; i < combinations; i++) {
      const key = i.toString(2)
                    .padStart(3, 0)
                    .split('')
                    .map((n, j) => matrix[n][j])
                    .join(" ")
                    
      output[key] = true;
  }
  
  return output
}

console.log(getAllCombinations([['one', 'two', 'three' ],[ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]]))
```

---

You can generalize this for `m x n` matrix. Instead of converting each to a binary number, you need to convert it to `base-m` and `padStart` to length `n`

```js
function getAllCombinations(matrix) {
  const rows = matrix.length,
        columns = matrix[0].length,
        combinations = rows ** columns;

  return Array.from({ length: combinations },
    (_, i) => i.toString(rows)
                .padStart(columns, 0)
                .split('')
                .map((n, j) => matrix[n][j])
  )
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(
    getAllCombinations( [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ) // 3 x 3 matrix
));

console.log(JSON.stringify(
    getAllCombinations( [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] ) // 4 x 2 matrix
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Code should work for you its recursive approach:

```js
const lowerWords = ['one', 'two', 'three']
const upperWords = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']

let result = {};

function getCombinations(index, caseType, arr) {
  if (index == 3) {
    arr[index] = (caseType == 'lower' ? lowerWords : upperWords)[index];
    result[arr.join(' ')] = true
    return
  }
  arr[index] = (caseType == 'lower' ? lowerWords : upperWords)[index];
  getCombinations(index + 1, 'lower', arr);
  getCombinations(index + 1, 'upper', arr);
}
getCombinations(0, 'lower', [])
getCombinations(0, 'upper', [])

console.log('resultresult', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can enumerate these directly. Here's one algorithm:

```
If we've reached the end of
the list, return the combination
the current recursion branch is
building.

Otherwise, create a new branch
that picks the next item from B,
while the current branch picks
the next item from A.
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, B, i=0, comb=[]){
  return i == A.length
         ? [comb]
         : f(A, B, i + 1, comb.concat(A[i])).concat(
           f(A, B, i + 1, comb.slice().concat(B[i])))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['one','two','three'], ['ONE','TWO','THREE'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalised version based on my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56255065/2034787) that handles a variable number of input arrays with varying lengths:

```js
const g = (arrs, i=0, comb=[]) =>
  !arrs.some(arr => i < arr.length)
  ? [comb]
  : arrs.reduce((acc, arr) => 
      i >= arr.length ? acc :
      acc.concat(g(arrs, i + 1, comb.slice().concat(arr[i])))
    , [])
    

// Example output
let input = [['ONE','TWO','THREE'], ['one','two'], [1,2,3,4]]

let str = ''
for (let line of g(input))
  str += JSON.stringify(line) + '\n'
console.log(str)
```