# Cartesian product of arrays that retains the index position of each item

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the cartesian product but I need each item to retain its index.

For example this is a cartesian product:

```
function cartesian() {
    var r = [], arg = arguments, max = arg.length-1;
    function helper(arr, i) {
        for (var j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
            var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
            a.push(arg[i][j]);
            if (i==max)
                r.push(a);
            else
                helper(a, i+1);
        }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
}
cartesian([1,2,3],[11,22,33],[111,222,333])
```

it returns this:

```
[ [ 1, 11, 111 ],
  [ 1, 11, 222 ],
  [ 1, 11, 333 ],
  [ 1, 22, 111 ],
  [ 1, 22, 222 ],
  [ 1, 22, 333 ],
  [ 1, 33, 111 ],
  [ 1, 33, 222 ],
  [ 1, 33, 333 ],
  [ 2, 11, 111 ],
  [ 2, 11, 222 ],
  [ 2, 11, 333 ],
  [ 2, 22, 111 ],
  [ 2, 22, 222 ],
  [ 2, 22, 333 ],
  [ 2, 33, 111 ],
  [ 2, 33, 222 ],
  [ 2, 33, 333 ],
  [ 3, 11, 111 ],
  [ 3, 11, 222 ],
  [ 3, 11, 333 ],
  [ 3, 22, 111 ],
  [ 3, 22, 222 ],
  [ 3, 22, 333 ],
  [ 3, 33, 111 ],
  [ 3, 33, 222 ],
  [ 3, 33, 333 ] ]
```

but I need it to return this:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 33],
  [1, 2, 333],
  [1, 22, 3],
  [1, 22, 33],
  [1, 22, 333],
  [1, 222, 3],
  [1, 222, 33],
  [1, 222, 333],
  [11, 2, 3],
  [11, 2, 33],
  [11, 2, 333],
  [11, 22, 3],
  [11, 22, 33],
  [11, 22, 333],
  [11, 222, 3],
  [11, 222, 33],
  [11, 222, 333],
  [111, 2, 3],
  [111, 2, 33],
  [111, 2, 333],
  [111, 22, 3],
  [111, 22, 33],
  [111, 22, 333],
  [111, 222, 3],
  [111, 222, 33],
  [111, 222, 333]
]
```

The array of arrays can be unsorted, but the arrays of numbers should be retain their indexes (in this case they are sorted but won't always be). Also if this algorithm has a name other than cartesian I would be interested in knowing.

Comment: @adiga it is not a duplicate of that link. None of the answers work for more than 2 arrays or keep the index order. I tried them all.

Comment: At least 3 answers work with 2D arrays of any length as an input including the accepted answer. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56252917/3082296), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56258092/3082296), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264734/3082296)

Comment: @adiga not true, first answer only accepts 2 arrays, the other answers do not retain index order. I tested them all.

Comment: Please go through the answer carefully .It takes a 2D array as an input. Just use `transpose([[1,2,3],[11,22,33],[111,222,333]])`

Comment: @adiga you're correct sorry I had a typo that's why it didnt work