# How to create values from two or more arrays using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a script in jQuery where it will create a sku_values for the variant items. I've managed to create an array for the items require in my sku.

`[78,79,80]` - item value for the first variant
`[81,82]` - item value for the 2nd

so what i want to do is create a concatenate value for these arrays

```
var variant_items = [];
if ($("input[name*='variant']").length > 0) {
   $("input[name*='variant']").each(function(index, variant){   
   variant_items[index] = [];
   var data = $(variant).data();
   if($('ul[data-variant-id='+data.variantId+'] li').length > 0){
    $('ul[data-variant-id='+data.variantId+'] li').each(function(i, item){                           
      variant_items[index].push($(item).data('item-id'));
    });
   }
 });
}
```

my expected output is

```
78_81
78_82
79_81
79_82
80_81
80_82
```

which is hard for me to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you add the HTML to the question so we can create a working example

Comment: i just wanted to create that values from the two arrays

Comment: You can use two nested loops, that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298912/javascript-generating-combinations-from-n-arrays-with-m-elements)

Answer (score 4):

use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const a1 = [78,79,80]
const a2 = [81,82]

const ans = a1.flatMap(e1 => a2.map(e2 => e1 + `_` + e2))

console.log(ans)
```

for an arbitrary number of arrays use recursion

```js
const a1 = [77, 78, 79, 80]
const a2 = [81, 82, 83]
const a3 = [84, 85]

const conc = (a, ...as) => 
  as.length === 0 ? a : a.flatMap(e1 => conc(...as).map(e2 => e1 + `_` + e2))

const ans = conc(a1, a2, a3)

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks, how about you for multiple arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and  [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
var arr1 = [78,79,80];
var arr2 = [81,82];

var output = arr1.map(function(e){
    return arr2.map(function(ee){
        return `${e}_${ee}`;
    })
}).reduce(function(acc, e){    
    return acc = acc.concat(e);
}, []);
console.log(output);
```