# How to create permutation of array in JS but with the given amount of chars

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, permutation

I have an array with some chars in it:

```js
    var ar1 = ["a", "1"];
```

I want to create arrays with all permutations of this array, BUT which would have had given amount of slots like so:

if amount of slots is 3 the arrays would look like this:

```js
    ["a", "1", "a"]
    ["1", "a", "1"]
    ["a", "a", "a"]
    ["1", "1", "1"]
    ["a", "a", "1"]
    ["1", "1", "a"]
    ["a", "1", "1"]
    ["1", "a", "a"]
```

and so on...

how can I make this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298912/javascript-generating-combinations-from-n-arrays-with-m-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this using recursion, something like this:

```js
function permutations(possibleCharacters, n){
    const result = [];

    if(n == 0){
        return [[]];
    }

    const subProblemResult = permutations(possibleCharacters, n - 1);

    for(let character of possibleCharacters){
        for(let sub of subProblemResult){
            result.push([character].concat(sub));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(permutations(["a", "1"], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Finding all possible combination of an input given the values and the length of each combination. inp = Input(Array), Len = Length of each combination.

```
function permutation(inp, len) {
   let posComb = 1,  r = 1;
   for ( let i =1; i<n/2+1; i++ )  {
      posComb = posComb * (inp-i+1)
      r = r * i;
      if ( posComb / r == inp ) return i;      
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Explanation: This finds all possible combination of a and input and a desired length. Now you just have to create an array and fill it with the permutation, now you know exactly how many.

Credit to dcieslak from CodeWar for Code.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest abusing `toString()` method:

```
var ar1 = ["a", "1"]

let n = 3
let base = ar1.length

let output = []

for(let i = 0; i < base**n; ++i) {
  output.push(i
    .toString(base)
    .padStart(n, '0')
    .split('')
    .map(x => ar1[parseInt(x, base)])
  )
}

console.log(output)
```

This way you can avoid recursion.

Comment: what does `digits` have to do with this? why are you doing base conversion? might be  you copied/pasted code from somewhere else?

Comment: I just wrote this code myself.  If you read it you wouldn't have to ask rhetorical questions.

Comment: these aren't rhetorical questions. i did read it and noticed `digits` is unused and `padStart` doesn't impact this particular program. these are obvious signs that this code has been copied/pasted from elsewhere.

Comment: `digits` was a leftover from previous version.  `padStart` does affect this program, without it leading zeroes would have been gone and arrays would have been of uneven length.  As for copying from elsewhere... I am `punund` on github, you can check my js code there. Look for the distinctive style (no semicolons).

Comment: i didn't accuse you of not writing it. i copy/paste my own programs all the time.

Comment: Even if it were the case (which it wasn't), why would it disqualify the answer?  I was moderating first posts and saw this question, unanswered for some time, and made an answer which woudn't use recursion, which is not always easy to follow.  If this were a copy-pasted code, I must be very lucky to have the same `ar1` variable as the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226007/discussion-between-punund-and-thank-you).