# How to generate all possible unique combinations of an array of objects, based on different properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, combinations, permutation

I have an array of objects and want to create all possible unique combinations based on two keys.

Example input -

```
[
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str1' },
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'body dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'legs combat1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'legs str1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'head dex1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' },
]
```

The ideal output would be something like

```
[
  [
    { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1' },
    { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
    { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' },
  ],
  [
    { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2' },
    { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
    { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' },
  ],
  [
    { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str' },
    { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
    { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' },
  ],
  ...etc
]
```

so that the final product would be all the combinations of each slot/spell/item without any repeats (disregarding the order).

My first thought was to organize the data into an a object for each slot and inside there an array for each effect.

```
const generateList = (data, slots, effects) => {
  const matches = {};
  slots.forEach(slot => {
    matches[slot] = {};
    effects.forEach(effect => {
      matches[slot][effect] = data.filter(item => item.slot === slot && item.spell === effect);
    })
  });

  return matches
};
```

Which generates

```
{
  body: {
    'combat.i': [
      { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1' },
      { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2' }
    ],
    'strength.i': [ { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str1' } ],
    'dexterity.i': [ { slot: 'body', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'body dex1' } ]
  },
  legs: {
    'combat.i': [ { slot: 'legs', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'legs combat1' } ],
    'strength.i': [ { slot: 'legs', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'legs str1' } ],
    'dexterity.i': [ { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' } ]
  },
  head: {
    'combat.i': [ { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' } ],
    'strength.i': [ { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' } ],
    'dexterity.i': [ { slot: 'head', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'head dex1' } ]
  },
]
```

I'm now kinda stuck on how to generate all the permutations to create the desired output, especially knowing that this will need to scale up to much larger numbers.  I know the answer is something to do with recursion but for the life of me, my silly front-end brain can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want "*all combinations*", that is the [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298912/1048572), **not** "permutations"!

Comment: By "*all the combinations of each slot/spell/item*", you mean all the possible distinct combinations of 3 objects where each combination has one object *per slot*, right? I.e. you don't want to recombine the objects?

Comment: Or wait, you don't just want all 3 different slots in each combination, but also all 3 different spells?

Comment: @Bergi correct, all the possible combinations of items, with each set of slots and spells being unique; meaning that in a given set, no slot or spell is duplicated

Comment: What should happen if there's more or less than 3 different slots in the data? Or more or less than 3 different spells? Do you still want to get exactly 3 items per combination?

Comment: @Bergi for my use purposes I'm going to force the user to select the same number of slots as spells.  That's a rabbit hole I don't want to go down.  This one is already deep enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it short and simple:

```js
function getTriples(items) {
  const result = [];
  for (const [i, firstItem] of items.entries()) {
    for (const [j, secondItem] of items.entries()) {
      for (const [k, thirdItem] of items.entries()) {
        if (i < j && j < k &&
            firstItem.slot != secondItem.slot && firstItem.slot != thirdItem.slot && secondItem.slot != thirdItem.slot &&
            firstItem.spell != secondItem.spell && firstItem.spell != thirdItem.spell && secondItem.spell != thirdItem.spell
        ) {
          result.push([firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(getTriples([
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str1' },
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'body dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'legs combat1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'legs str1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'head dex1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' },
]), null, 4);
document.body.style = "white-space: pre; font-family: monospace";
```

Now to make this more generic for arbitrary combination sizes, you can use recursion instead of nesting the loops, but it gets a bit more complicated:

```
function getCombinations(size, items) {
  const result = [];
  function generate(combination, index) {
    if (combination.length >= size) {
      result.push(combination);
    } else {
      for (let i=index; i<items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        if (combination.every(prevItem =>
          prevItem.slot != item.slot && prevItem.spell != item.spell
        )) {
          generate([...combination, item], i+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  generate([], 0);
  return result;
}
```

Just ensure that the `items` contain more unique slot values and more unique spell values than the chosen `size`, or you'll get no results.

Finally, to make it generic over the properties that should be distinct between them items of one combination, you can introduce a parameter for those as well:

```js
function getCombinations(properties, size, items) {
  const result = [];
  function generate(combination, index) {
    if (combination.length >= size) {
      result.push(combination);
    } else {
      for (let i=index; i<items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        if (properties.every(prop =>
          combination.every(prevItem =>
            prevItem[prop] != item[prop]
          )
        )) {
          generate([...combination, item], i+1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  generate([], 0);
  return result;
}

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(getCombinations(['slot', 'spell'], 3, [
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2'},
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str1' },
  { slot: 'body', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'body dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'legs dex1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'legs combat1' },
  { slot: 'legs', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'legs str1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'dexterity.i', item: 'head dex1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' },
  { slot: 'head', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'head str1' },
]), null, 4);
document.body.style = "white-space: pre; font-family: monospace";
```

Comment: I _think_ you nailed it.  How so simple?  Also, how do I make this work for up to 8 slots/spells without having to get super verbose?

Comment: It should work out of the box if you have more than 3 slots or more than 3 spells, it'll always choose 3 items with non-overlapping slot/spell values.

Comment: @larz Ah actually it doesn't have to be always 3 items. I've update the answer to separate this parameter properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = [
    { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat1' },
    { slot: 'body', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'body combat2' },
    // Other items...
];

// Organize the data
let organized = {};
items.forEach(item => {
    if (!organized[item.slot]) {
        organized[item.slot] = {};
    }
    if (!organized[item.slot][item.spell]) {
        organized[item.slot][item.spell] = [];
    }
    organized[item.slot][item.spell].push(item);
});

// Generate combinations
function cartesian(...args) {
    var r = [], max = args.length-1;
    function helper(arr, i) {
        for (var j=0, l=args[i].length; j<l; j++) {
            var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
            a.push(args[i][j]);
            if (i==max)
                r.push(a);
            else
                helper(a, i+1);
        }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
}

let slotCombinations = Object.values(organized).map(spell => Object.values(spell).flat());
let allCombinations = cartesian(...slotCombinations);

// Example to print the first 5 combinations for brevity
allCombinations.slice(0, 5).forEach(combo => console.log(combo));
```

Comment: This is beautiful but it's not unique for slot/spell combos.  An item in the list has two pieces with the same `spell`

Comment: hmm...i'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want :

```
function generateAllUniqueCombinations(items) {
  // Group items by their slot and then by spell within each slot to facilitate combination generation.
  const groupedBySlotAndSpell = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (!acc[item.slot]) acc[item.slot] = {};
    if (!acc[item.slot][item.spell]) acc[item.slot][item.spell] = [];
    acc[item.slot][item.spell].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  // Generate all combinations of spells for each slot.
  function findAllSpellCombinations(slots) {
    if (slots.length === 0) return [[]];

    const firstSlotSpells = Object.keys(groupedBySlotAndSpell[slots[0]]);
    const combinationsWithoutFirst = findAllSpellCombinations(slots.slice(1));

    let allCombinations = [];
    firstSlotSpells.forEach((spell) => {
      combinationsWithoutFirst.forEach((combination) => {
        allCombinations.push([{ slot: slots[0], spell }, ...combination]);
      });
    });

    return allCombinations;
  }

  // Convert the slot-spell combinations into item combinations.
  function toItemCombinations(spellCombinations) {
    return spellCombinations.map((combination) =>
      combination.map(
        ({ slot, spell }) =>
          groupedBySlotAndSpell[slot][spell].find((item) => true) // Simply select the first matching item
      )
    );
  }

  const slots = Object.keys(groupedBySlotAndSpell);
  const spellCombinations = findAllSpellCombinations(slots);

  return toItemCombinations(spellCombinations);
}

// Example usage with the provided input array
const items = [
  { slot: "body", spell: "combat.i", item: "body combat1" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "combat.i", item: "body combat2" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "strength.i", item: "body str1" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "body dex1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "legs dex1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "combat.i", item: "legs combat1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "strength.i", item: "legs str1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "head dex1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "combat.i", item: "head combat1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "strength.i", item: "head str1" },
];

const uniqueCombinations = generateAllUniqueCombinations(items);
console.log(uniqueCombinations);
```

Comment: Unfortunately still generating options like ` { slot: 'body', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'body str1' },
    { slot: 'legs', spell: 'strength.i', item: 'legs str1' },
    { slot: 'head', spell: 'combat.i', item: 'head combat1' }`
 with two `strength.i` items.
Also, would it be extensive to 8 spells/slots?  Something about recursion?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I can do, you need to do your own research to suit your desired result :

```
const items = [
  { slot: "body", spell: "combat.i", item: "body combat1" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "combat.i", item: "body combat2" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "strength.i", item: "body str1" },
  { slot: "body", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "body dex1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "legs dex1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "combat.i", item: "legs combat1" },
  { slot: "legs", spell: "strength.i", item: "legs str1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "dexterity.i", item: "head dex1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "combat.i", item: "head combat1" },
  { slot: "head", spell: "strength.i", item: "head str1" },
  // Add more items for up to 8 slots/spells if needed
];

function groupItemsBySlot(items) {
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.slot] = acc[item.slot] || [];
    acc[item.slot].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function generateCombinations(
  groupedItems,
  currentSlotIndex = 0,
  currentCombination = [],
  usedSpells = new Set(),
  allCombinations = []
) {
  const slots = Object.keys(groupedItems);
  if (currentSlotIndex === slots.length) {
    // Base case: all slots processed
    allCombinations.push([...currentCombination]);
    return;
  }

  const currentSlot = slots[currentSlotIndex];
  groupedItems[currentSlot].forEach((item) => {
    if (!usedSpells.has(item.spell)) {
      // Check if the spell is not yet used
      usedSpells.add(item.spell); // Mark the spell as used
      generateCombinations(
        groupedItems,
        currentSlotIndex + 1,
        [...currentCombination, item],
        new Set(usedSpells),
        allCombinations
      );
      usedSpells.delete(item.spell); // Unmark the spell for the next iteration
    }
  });

  if (currentSlotIndex === 0) {
    // Return the result only after the first call completes
    return allCombinations;
  }
}

const groupedItems = groupItemsBySlot(items);
const uniqueCombinations = generateCombinations(groupedItems);
console.log(uniqueCombinations);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to organize the data by 'slot' first, and then by 'spell' within each slot is a good start. After organizing the data, you can generate the combinations.

```
# Example input
items = [
    {'slot': 'body', 'spell': 'combat.i', 'item': 'body combat1'},
    {'slot': 'body', 'spell': 'combat.i', 'item': 'body combat2'},
    {'slot': 'body', 'spell': 'strength.i', 'item': 'body str1'},
    {'slot': 'body', 'spell': 'dexterity.i', 'item': 'body dex1'},
    {'slot': 'legs', 'spell': 'dexterity.i', 'item': 'legs dex1'},
    {'slot': 'legs', 'spell': 'combat.i', 'item': 'legs combat1'},
    {'slot': 'legs', 'spell': 'strength.i', 'item': 'legs str1'},
    {'slot': 'head', 'spell': 'dexterity.i', 'item': 'head dex1'},
    {'slot': 'head', 'spell': 'combat.i', 'item': 'head combat1'},
    {'slot': 'head', 'spell': 'strength.i', 'item': 'head str1'},
]

# Step 1: Organize the data
organized = {}
for item in items:
    slot = item['slot']
    spell = item['spell']
    if slot not in organized:
        organized[slot] = {}
    if spell not in organized[slot]:
        organized[slot][spell] = []
    organized[slot][spell].append(item)

# Step 2: Generate combinations
# Convert each slot's spells into a list of items
slot_combinations = [list(spell.values()) for spell in organized.values()]
# Generate all combinations using product
all_combinations = list(product(*[item for sublist in slot_combinations for item in sublist]))

# Convert from tuple back to list format for the final output
final_combinations = [[item for item in combo] for combo in all_combinations]

# Example to print the first 5 combinations for brevity
for combo in final_combinations[:5]:
    print(combo)
```

Comment: I am only following 50%.  Is this javascript?  Why slot vs spell first when i'm permutating on both?

Comment: sorry I was working with python earlier, carried away by it, let me try with javascript