# Test All Combinations a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Tags: javascript, for-loop, combinations, alphabet

I need to check all combinations a-z, with a string length of 2.
So, example output would be:

aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
etc.

I've been trying to use for loop, but to no success. This is what I got:

```
var length = 2;
var password = [];
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for(var l = 0; l < length; l++)
{
    for(var c = 0; c < 62; c++)
    {
        password[c] = possible.charAt(c);
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use 2 for loops.  One for the first letter, one for the second.  Give it a shot and come back with what you tried.

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Well, I didn't get far, and stuck. I don't want to usetwo for-loops like that, since I want to be able to change the length later.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values) might help you.

Comment: `I don't want to usetwo for-loops like that` then recursion is your direction.

Answer (score 4):

tCheck out this: http://jsfiddle.net/n0m4wvpq/

```
var passwords = function(chars, length){
    var index=[];
    chars = chars.split("");

    (function loop(base, i){
        for(var k=0; k< chars.length; k++) {
            if(i>1) loop(base+chars[k], i-1);
            else index.push(base+chars[k]);
        }
    })("", length);

    return index;
}

var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var length = 2;
passwords(possible, length);
```

---

**FUN FACT:**

This function can be used to generate [Jorge Louis Borges "Library of Babel"](http://hyperdiscordia.crywalt.com/library_of_babel.html):

```
var libraryOfBabel = passwords("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,.", 1312000);
```

PS.: Don't try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
for(var x of possible){
    for(var y of possible){
        console.log(x+y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y6qnsem4/

```
var length = 2;
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split('');
console.log(combine(length));

function combine(length, level, previous)
{
  var level = level || 1;
  var previous = previous || possible;
  var ret = [];

  previous.map(function(el) {
     possible.map(function(letter) {
        ret.push(el + letter);
     });
  });

  if (level < length - 1) ret = combine(length, level + 1, ret);

  return ret;
}
```

It returns array of combinations, but it is not difficult to join it into the string like this `alert([1,2,3].join(','))`. And it works for any length (but takes more and more time, of course, because number of elements in array will be equal to `possible.length ^ length`. For `possible.length = 62` and `length = 2` there are 3844 combinations. And for `length = 4` you will 'kill/hang' your browser tab with 14776336 combinations).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split(''),
    length = 2,
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    step,
    comb;

for (i; i < possible.length; i++) {
    step = possible[i];
    console.log("==============" + step + "==============");
    for (j; j < possible.length; j++) {
        comb  = step + '' + possible.slice(j, j + (length - 1)).join('');
        console.log(comb);
    }
    j = 0;
}
```