# How can I create all combinations of this object's keys/values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, combinations, permutation

I have the following JavaScript object structure:

```
var options = {
    optionOne: [true, false],
    optionTwo: [true, false],
    optionThree: [
        null,
        {property1: 9, property2: 7},
        {property1: 4, property2: 12},
        {property1: 16, property2: 14}
    ]
};
```

Please note that the number of key/pairs in this object will differ. So there might actually be `optionFour`, `optionFive`, etc., and each option can have any number or type of values for its array.

I need to iterate through this object and create an array containing objects of all possible option combinations:

```
[
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, true,  optionThree: null},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, true,  optionThree: null},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, false, optionThree: null},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, false, optionThree: null},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 9, property2: 7}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 9, property2: 7}},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 9, property2: 7}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 9, property2: 7}},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 4, property2: 12}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 4, property2: 12}},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 4, property2: 12}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 4, property2: 12}},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 16, property2: 14}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, true,  optionThree: {property1: 16, property2: 14}},
    {optionOne: true,  optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 16, property2: 14}},
    {optionOne: false, optionTwo, false, optionThree: {property1: 16, property2: 14}}
]
```

I'm struggling on how to accomplish this but am fairly confident the answer lies in recursion.

Can the algorithm gods help me?

Comment: how about this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values

Comment: HA -- that's *exactly* the one I've been looking at for the past hour and trying to model :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function getCombinations(options, optionIndex, results, current) {
    var allKeys = Object.keys(options);
    var optionKey = allKeys[optionIndex];

    var vals = options[optionKey];

    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        current[optionKey] = vals[i];

        if (optionIndex + 1 < allKeys.length) {
            getCombinations(options, optionIndex + 1, results, current);
        } else {
            // The easiest way to clone an object.
            var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(current));
            results.push(res);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var results = getCombinations(options, 0, [], {});
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Shedal/4n8aLcu3/4/).

Comment: @ChadJohnson I would also wrap this into a class for better usability. Then you'd be able to use it like this: `(new Permuter(options)).getPermutations()`. Or something similar where you don't have to pass in base recursion values.

Comment: Thank you sir. I hope all is well with you and your family there in Ukraine!

Comment: Nice solution! One minor suggestion would be to add default parameter values so that we can call the method by passing the object only.

Comment: Thank you. You are life saver

Answer (score 2):

This was recently resurrected, and I think modern JS offers a cleaner way to write this.

```js
const crossproduct = (xss) => 
  xss.reduce((xs, ys) => xs.flatMap(x => ys.map(y => [...x, y])), [[]])

const combinations = (o, keys = Object .keys (o), vals = Object .values (o)) =>
  crossproduct(vals).map(xs => Object.fromEntries(xs.map ((x, i) => [keys[i], x])))


const options = {optionOne: [true, false], optionTwo: [true, false], optionThree: [null, {property1: 9, property2: 7}, {property1: 4, property2: 12}, {property1: 16, property2: 14}]}

console .log (JSON .stringify (
  combinations (options)
, null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with a `crossproduct` function which, for instance, takes

```
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['T', 'F']]
```

and returns

```
[
  [1, 'a', 'T'], [1, 'a', 'F'], [1, 'b', 'T'], [1, 'b', 'F'], [1, 'c', 'T'], [1, 'c', 'F'], 
  [2, 'a', 'T'], [2, 'a', 'F'], [2, 'b', 'T'], [2, 'b', 'F'], [2, 'c', 'T'], [2, 'c', 'F']
]
```

Then `combinations` takes our object apart with `Object.keys`, and `Object.values`, passes the values to `crossproduct`, then for each array in the result, maps over the values, associating the corresponding key with each, then rehydrating an object with `Object.fromEntries`.

This order is what seems like the logical order of results to me.  But if we swapped out the returned expression for `crossproduct` with the following, we would get the order mentioned in the question:

```js
  xss .reduce ((xs, ys) => ys .flatMap (y => xs .map (x => [...x, y])), [[]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improvement, based on Dmytro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839413/1870795):

```
function getPermutations(object, index = 0, current = {}, results = []) {
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  const key = keys[index];
  const values = object[key];

  for (const value of values) {
    current[key] = value;
    const nextIndex = index + 1;

    if (nextIndex < keys.length) {
      this.getPermutations(object, nextIndex, current, results);
    } else {
      const result = Object.assign({}, current);
      results.push(result);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Improvements:

- Works for any kind of value, even if the value is a function
- Default argument values, can be easily invoked with: `const p = getPermutations(object);`
- Minor semantic improvements