# How to group array and sum by a specific key using javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data as follows:

```
const results = [
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 }
];
```

And I want to map it to get the combinations of all keys with sum of count. Thus I want to get something as follows:

```
const mappedResults = [
  { make: "audi", fuel: undefined, model: undefined, count: 8 + 2 + 5 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: undefined, count: 2 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: undefined, count: 8 + 5 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 },

  { make: "audi", fuel: undefined, model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: undefined, model: "a3", count: 2 + 5 },

  { make: undefined, fuel: undefined, model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: undefined, fuel: undefined, model: "a3", count: 2 + 5 },

  { make: undefined, fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: undefined, fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 },
  { make: undefined, fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 },

  { make: undefined, fuel: "gasoline", model: undefined, count: 8 + 5 },
  { make: undefined, fuel: "diesel", model: undefined, count: 2 }
];
```

I 'm really not sure how to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing something as follows:

```
const groupedByMake = groupBy(results, "make");
const groupedByModel = groupBy(results, "model");
const groupedByFuel = groupBy(results, "fuel");
let groupedByMakeModel = {}
results.reduce(function (r, o) {
  var key = o.make + "-" + o.model;

  if (!groupedByMakeModel[key]) {
    groupedByMakeModel[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(groupedByMakeModel[key]);
  } else {
    groupedByMakeModel[key].count += o.count;
  }

  return r;
}, []);

let groupedByMakeFuel = {}
results.reduce(function (r, o) {
  var key = o.make + "-" + o.fuel;

  if (!groupedByMakeFuel[key]) {
    groupedByMakeFuel[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(groupedByMakeFuel[key]);
  } else {
    groupedByMakeFuel[key].count += o.count;
  }

  return r;
}, []);

let groupedByModelFuel = {}
results.reduce(function (r, o) {
  var key = o.model + "-" + o.fuel;

  if (!groupedByModelFuel[key]) {
    groupedByModelFuel[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(groupedByModelFuel[key]);
  } else {
    groupedByModelFuel[key].count += o.count;
  }

  return r;
}, []);

let groupedByMakeModelFuel = {}
results.reduce(function (r, o) {
  var key = o.make + "-" + o.model + "-" + o.fuel;

  if (!groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]) {
    groupedByMakeModelFuel[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]);
  } else {
    groupedByMakeModelFuel[key].count += o.count;
  }

  return r;
}, []);


const result = []

each(keys(groupedByMake), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: key,
    model: undefined,
    fuel: undefined,
    count: sumBy(groupedByMake[key], 'count')
  })
})
each(keys(groupedByModel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: undefined,
    model: key,
    fuel: undefined,
    count: sumBy(groupedByModel[key], 'count')
  })
})
each(keys(groupedByFuel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: undefined,
    model: undefined,
    fuel: key,
    count: sumBy(groupedByFuel[key], 'count')
  })
})

each(keys(groupedByMakeModel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: groupedByMakeModel[key]?.make,
    model: groupedByMakeModel[key]?.model,
    fuel: undefined,
    count: groupedByMakeModel[key]?.count
  })
})

each(keys(groupedByMakeFuel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: groupedByMakeFuel[key]?.make,
    model: undefined,
    fuel: groupedByMakeFuel[key]?.fuel,
    count: groupedByMakeFuel[key]?.count
  })
})

each(keys(groupedByModelFuel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: undefined,
    model: groupedByModelFuel[key]?.model,
    fuel: groupedByModelFuel[key]?.fuel,
    count: groupedByModelFuel[key]?.count
  })
})

each(keys(groupedByMakeModelFuel), key => {
  return result.push({
    make: groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]?.make,
    model: groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]?.model,
    fuel: groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]?.fuel,
    count: groupedByMakeModelFuel[key]?.count
  })
})

console.log("result: ", result)
```

[Here is the playground.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/lodash-playground-forked-557exe?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

But is there a better or faster way?

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a binary pattern with the length of the grouping keys and add `count` according to the group.

```js
const
    data = [{ make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 }, { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 }, { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 }],
    keys = ['make', 'fuel', 'model'],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        let i = 2 ** keys.length;
        while (i--) {
            const
                pattern = i.toString(2).padStart(keys.length, 0),
                key = keys.map((k, j) => +pattern[j] ? o[k] : '').join('|');

            r[key] ??= { ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, j) => [k, +pattern[j] ? o[k] : undefined])), count: 0 };
            r[key].count += o.count;  
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A different approach by building a tree first with recursion and then take all totals from the leaves and their path properties.

```js
const
    data = [{ make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 }, { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 }, { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 }],
    keys = ['make', 'fuel', 'model'],
    iter = (source, target, keys) => {
        const
            key = keys[0],
            add = (key, value) => {
                let item = (target.children ??= []).find(q => q[key] === value);
                if (!item) target.children.push(item = { [key]: value });
                iter(source, item, keys.slice(1));
            };
            
        if (keys.length) {
            add(key, source[key]);
            add(key, undefined);
        } else {
            target.count = (target.count || 0) + source.count;
        }
    },
    totals = p => ({ children, ...o }) => children?.flatMap(totals({ ...p, ...o })) || { ...p, ...o },
    temp = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        iter(o, { children: r }, keys);
        return r;
    }, []),
    result = temp.flatMap(totals({}));

console.log(result);
console.log(temp); // how it's done
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get _Error: Unexpected token_ for `r[key] ??= {`

Comment: replace [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) pattern `x ??= y;` with assignment with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) `x = x || y;`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const data = [
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 }
];

const combinations = Object.values(data.reduce((res, {count, ...rest}) => 
    Object.entries(rest).reduce(
      (keys, [k, v]) =>  [{[k]: undefined }, {[k]: v}]
        .flatMap(r => keys.length > 0? keys.flatMap(k => ({...k, ...r})): [r])
   , []).reduce((res, d) => {
      const k = JSON.stringify(d)
     if(k === "{}"){
       return res
     }
     const existing = res[k] || {...d, count:0}
     return {
       ...res,
       [k]: {...existing, count: existing.count + count}
     }
   }, res)
, {} ))

console.log(combinations)
```

this part create all the combination of key value and undefined

```
Object.entries(rest).reduce(
      (keys, [k, v]) =>  [{[k]: undefined }, {[k]: v}]
        .flatMap(r => keys.length > 0? keys.flatMap(k => ({...k, ...r})): [r])
   , [])
```

once you have got all the combinations you can create the key (I've used `JSON.stringify` for that)

then you just create an object with the keys and sum the counts if that key is already present

```
.reduce((res, d) => {
      const k = JSON.stringify(d)
     if(k === "{}"){
       return res
     }
     const existing = res[k] || {...d, count:0}
     return {
       ...res,
       [k]: {...existing, count: existing.count + count}
     }
   }, res)
```

And finally you get rid of the keys and return just the values using `Object.values`

with this implementation you can count elements with different attributes (count must be present tough)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to handle this:

1. Create an object that has the unique values of all keys (except count), we should get:

   ```
   {make: [undefined, 'audi'], fuel: [undefined, 'gasoline', 'diesel'], model: [undefined, 'a1', 'a3']}
   ```
2. Create a `calculateCount` function that calculates the count provided the values, example:

   ```
   calculateCount(results, {make: 'audi'}) === 15
   ```
3. Use a permutation functions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483297/1354378), to create all possible combinations from the object that we created on step 1
4. Calculate the sum of each combination, using the `calculateCount` function

```js
const results = [
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a1", count: 8 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "diesel", model: "a3", count: 2 },
  { make: "audi", fuel: "gasoline", model: "a3", count: 5 },
];

const keys = ['make', 'fuel', 'model'];

// create sets from keys, so that we can have the unique values of each key + undefined
const sets = results.reduce((obj, item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (!obj[key].includes(value)) obj[key].push(value)
      }
      else {
        obj[key] = [undefined, value]
      }
    }
  });
  
  return obj;
}, {});

function calculateCount(arr, values) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, item) => {
    const match = Object.entries(values).every(([key, value]) => {
      // proceed if the value is undefined, or equal with item's value
      return value === undefined || value === item[key];
    })
            
    return match ? sum + item.count : sum;
  }, 0)
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483297/1354378
function getPermutations(object, index = 0, current = {}, results = []) {
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  const key = keys[index];
  const values = object[key];

  for (const value of values) {
    current[key] = value;
    const nextIndex = index + 1;

    if (nextIndex < keys.length) {
      this.getPermutations(object, nextIndex, current, results);
    } else {
      const result = Object.assign({}, current);
      results.push(result);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

const all = getPermutations(sets).map(item => {
  return {
    ...item,
    count: calculateCount(results, item), // you can do this in getPermutations as well
  }
})

console.log(all)
```