# Recursive unique javascript method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in this form ...

- arr[itemDescription]

  - [0] someValue1
  - [1] someotherValue1
- arr[itemDescription]

  - [0] someValue2
  - [1] someotherValue2
- arr[itemDescription]

  - [0] someValue3
  - [1] someotherValue3
- ....

Now i would like to generate all possible variations where i have an array with the first item combined with the other elements, the second element combined with the other elements and so on. Like:

- [someValue1][someValue2][someValue3]
- [someValue1][someotherValue2][someValue3]
- [someValue1][someotherValue2][someotherValue3]
- ....

to sum up, for the folowing input array:

```
[[11, 12], [21, 22], [31, 32]];
```

I need to obtain an output array like

```
[[11, 21, 31], [11, 21, 32], [11, 22, 31], [11, 22, 32], [12, 21, 31], [12, 21, 32], [12, 22, 31], [12, 22, 32]];
```

Can somebody help me how I would do that in javascript?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What did you try so far? Put down some code or you're gonna get downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Two nested `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks all :) I will read/learn some more ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding All Combinations of JavaScript array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this solution. To decide to choose the index of sub array iside input array, I use array dimension modulo global index :

```js
var input = [[11, 12], [21, 22], [31, 32]];
var dim = Math.pow(2, input.length);
var output = new Array(dim);
output.fill(0);
input.forEach((x,i) => {
  var limit = dim / Math.pow(2, i+1);
  output.forEach((y,j,arr) => {
    var index = Math.floor((j+1)/limit) % 2;
    if (i === 0)
      arr[j] = [x[index]];
    else
      arr[j].push(x[index]);
  });
});
console.log(output);
```