# Generation cartesian product objects from array values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm building an array of objects out of the permutations of the entries in some arrays. My first stab at the code is below, it should help to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
permutationsArray = (array1, array2, array3) => {
  const arrayOfObjects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < array3.length; k++) {
          arrayOfObjects.push({
            aConstant: 'some constant',
            key1: array1[i],
            key2: array2[j],
            key3: array3[k],
          });
        }
      }
    }
  return arrayOfObjects;
};
```

I'm really unhappy with having nested `for` loops to achieve this. Alternatives I have looked at are:

- Use nested mapping and flatten the tree created
- Attempt a recursive system similar to [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values#)

I'm looking for input as to whether I'm going in the right direction with solving this. Ideally I want to get to the point where I can supply as many arrays as I wanted.

A big problem I'm seeing is how to name the keys with recursion.

Comment: This might help with key names: `var obj = { aConstant: 'some constant'}; obj['key' + 1] = array1[i];` where `1` can be based on a counter

Comment: If you aways have three arrays, then nested loops is the best way. Otherwise look for a good JS implementation of **Cartesian product**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298912/javascript-generating-combinations-from-n-arrays-with-m-elements)

Comment: thanks for your input everyone, `cartesian product` was the subject I needed to start reading into more!

Comment: I don't know if it's optimal way but you can test it with sets of different array and calculate the time processed.

Comment: I'll have a go at that! at the moment it's the only way I can think of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that's not a problem with `permutations`, it's exactly `Cartesian product`.

In `set` theory (and, usually, in other parts of **mathematics**), a `Cartesian product` is a **mathematical** operation that returns a `set` from multiple **sets**.

[image]

You can achieve that using `ES6` features like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b) methods.

```js
function cartesianProduct(...arrays) {
  return [...arrays].reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map(x => b.map(y => x.concat(y)))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []), [[]]);
}
console.log(cartesianProduct([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]));
```

Comment: Has anyone seen an implementation of n-fold cartesian product that is memory efficient? This implementation fails for my 6 input sets that result in 10MM combinations.

Comment: @oravecz - It's all those `concat` calls, each of which creates a new array. Surely they can't be necessary...