# All Array Combination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics

Need all possible combinations of an array including the reverse of a combination too.

Eg:

```
var b = ['a1','b1','a','b'];
```

Need combinations as:

```
a1,b1,a,b
a1b1,a1a,a1b, b1a1,b1a,b1b, ......,
a1b1a,a1b1b,a1ab1,a1bb1,........,
a1b1ab,a1b1ba.....bab1a1
```

All 64 combinations (if array has 4 elements).
I found solution in java using ArrayList and Collection API, but right now I need a pure JavaScript ES5 solution.

I tried the following, but it only provides lesser combinations.

```
function getCombinations(chars) {
    var result = [];
    var f = function (prefix, chars) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
            f(prefix + chars[i], chars.slice(i + 1));
        }
    }
    f('', chars);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values How does it happen that you expect 64 values? shouldn't it be 256?

Comment: I had already gone through the above link and it mainly deals with multiple arrays.

Comment: @Bergi But this current question also includes different kinds of permutations.

Comment: @Bergi Really? like anyone would find that question, named "Recursively Concatenate Strings in Array JavaScript."

Comment: @vivek_23 The desired results ("*Need combinations as*") don't include any permutations? I thought the OP was looking for permutations as first as well (due to the tag that I now removed), but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: @גלעדברקן No, I wouldn't expect anyone to find that particular post, but it still answers the same question: computing the power set.

Comment: @Bergi the question you marked is also not a duplicate since it doesn't include all permutations of the combinations. (I also have a meta warning about moderators unilaterally marking duplicates they have answered themselves.)

Comment: @Bergi Ok it's combinations(removing duplicate permutations) but it still needs different combinations. In your answer there, you don't have a combination as you showed in the output there, for example `cdab`.

Comment: @vivek_23 You might be right - the desired results here contain both `a1b1` and `b1a1`, also `a1b1ba` and `bab1a1` which are permutations. Others seem to be missing though.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, never mind.

Comment: I cut my function down to three lines :)

Comment: Producing the power set, all permutations, etc., are a well-documented problems, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.  You have not yet performed a straightforward trace of your code.  Please explain where you're stuck in the development or debugging process.

Comment: I have answered another question like this. I hope it will help you also. Please check: stackoverflow.com/a/65535210/2184182

Comment: If you need to preserve order, i.e. disallow `[ "b1", "a1" ]`, `[ "b", "b1", "a1" ]`, etc., then see [From array, generate all distinct, non-empty subarrays, with preserved order](/q/60304208/4642212).

Answer (score 5):

Let's put your request into words: for each starting element, append all permutations of all combinations of the rest of the elements.

```js
function f(A, comb=[], result=[comb]){
  return A.reduce((acc, a, i) => acc.concat(f(A.slice(0,i).concat(A.slice(i+1)), comb.concat(a))), result);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])));
```

Comment: I really don't mean to get catty - I think the main purpose of asking questions on StackOverflow (as newbies) is to learn, not to just get the problem solved. So, cutting down the solution to 3 lines might be convenient but it's really heavy on the eyes. A good solution, though, nonetheless.

Comment: @Smytt on the contrary - my answer offers a wonderful opportunity for the OP and others to learn. Can you tell how?

Comment: the way you name you variables, using capital letters and incomplete words can be misleading. also, function call within function call - it just needs a lot of dissection to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @Smytt omg. `A` is one of the most common ways to label an array (virtually every online question lists `A[i]` as array selections). `result` means exactly what it is labeled as, and `comb` is short for "combination" (is that really an issue?). Finally, we have a recursive call and a call to two JavaScript array methods. What are you talking about? It sounds to me like you take an issue with having to learn new things.

Comment: No need to get defensive. As I said, I only shared an opinion.

Comment: @Smytt I would characterise that as "incredulous" rather than "defensive." Nevertheless, it's all good :)

Comment: I think instead of encoding into json do `output.map(item=>item.join('')).join(',')`

Answer (score 1):

a somewhat simple recursion will deal with this issue. Check it out:

```js
function getCombinations(chars) {
  let combinations = [];
  chars.forEach((char, i) => {
    let word = '';
    buildWord(word + char, [i], chars, combinations)
  });
  return combinations;
}

function buildWord(word, usedIndexes, chars, combinations) {
  combinations.push(word);
  chars.forEach((char, i) => {
    if (usedIndexes.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      let newUsedIndexesArray = Array.from(usedIndexes);
      newUsedIndexesArray.push(i);
      buildWord(word + char, newUsedIndexesArray, chars, combinations)
    }
  });
}

console.log('Total: ' + getCombinations(['a1', 'b1', 'a', 'b']).length)
console.log(getCombinations(['a1', 'b1', 'a', 'b']))
```

Comment: Yes. I edited it. I was under the assumption that the permutations need to include all 4 members. so This works now - permutations without repetition of members

Comment: Is this JavaScript ES5?

Comment: Just edited it to fit your ES5 requirement. Both the spread operator (...) and Array.prototype.includes come later and could not be used. As you see, the code gets a tad heavier on the eye.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an iterative approach. We go from permutation length of 1 till length(no. of characters in the given `chars`) and generate all possible combinations for each length. 
We maintain a `set` to avoid duplicates and `isValidPermutation()` check to see whether a combination is possible from given set of `chars` to avoid invalid combinations.

```js
function getCombinations(chars) {
  if (chars === undefined || chars === null || chars.length === 0) return [];
  var final_result = [];
  var temp_result_1 = chars.slice();
  var set = {};
  /* for initial set of elements */
  for (var i = 0; i < temp_result_1.length; ++i) {
    if (set[temp_result_1[i]] === undefined) {
      set[temp_result_1[i]] = true;
      final_result.push(temp_result_1[i]);
    }
  }

  /* go from 2 to length(since length 1 is captured above) to get all permutations of combinations */
  for (var len = 2; len <= chars.length; ++len) {
    var temp_result_2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
      for (var j = 0; j < temp_result_1.length; ++j) {
        var current_permutation = chars[i] + "," + temp_result_1[j];
        if (set[current_permutation] === undefined && isValidPermutation(current_permutation, chars)) {
          temp_result_2.push(current_permutation);
          set[current_permutation] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    temp_result_1 = temp_result_2;
    final_result = final_result.concat(temp_result_1);
  }

  return final_result.map((each) => each.split(",").join(""));
}
/* to check if actually a combination is true and possible from current set of chars */
function isValidPermutation(current_permutation, chars) {
  var hash = {};
  current_permutation = current_permutation.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
    if (hash[chars[i]] === undefined) hash[chars[i]] = 0;
    hash[chars[i]]++;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < current_permutation.length; ++i) {
    hash[current_permutation[i]]--;
    if (hash[current_permutation[i]] < 0) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

var b = ['a1', 'b1', 'a', 'b'];
console.log(getCombinations(b));
```

Since you need a ECMAScript 5 solution, you change the last line

```
return final_result.map((each) => each.split(",").join(""));
```

to

```
 for(var i=0;i<final_result.length;++i){
      final_result[i] = final_result[i].split(",").join("");
  }

  return final_result;
```