# Filtering a list of results with a 3 tier menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Link to the Codepen](https://codepen.io/jathon77/pen/vYYoGWa)

```js
$('.series-nav li').on('click', handleSeriesClick);
$('.body-nav li').on('click', handleBodyClick);
$('.style-nav li').on('click', handleStyleClick);

SERIES = [];
BODY = [];
STYLE = [];

function handleSeriesClick(el) {
  const selected = $(el.currentTarget).data('series');
  
  if (selected === 'all') {
    SERIES = [];
  } else {
    const index = SERIES.indexOf(selected);

    if (index !== -1) {
      SERIES.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      SERIES.push(selected);
    }
  }
  
  updateNav('series');
}

function handleBodyClick(el) {
  const selected = $(el.currentTarget).data('body');
  
  if (selected === 'all') {
    BODY = [];
  } else {
    const index = BODY.indexOf(selected);

    if (index !== -1) {
      BODY.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      BODY.push(selected);
    }
  }
  
  updateNav('body');
}

function handleStyleClick(el) {
  const selected = $(el.currentTarget).data('style');
  
  if (selected === 'all') {
    STYLE = [];
  } else {
    const index = STYLE.indexOf(selected);

    if (index !== -1) {
      STYLE.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      STYLE.push(selected);
    }
  }
  
  updateNav('style');
}

function updateNav(nav) {
  let items = '';
  let LIST = '';

  if (nav === "series") {
    items = $('.series-nav li');
    LIST = SERIES;
  } else if (nav === "body") {
    items = $('.body-nav li');
    LIST = BODY;
  } else if (nav === "style") {
    items = $('.style-nav li');
    LIST = STYLE;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  $.each(items, (i, el) => {
    const item = $(el);
    const val = item.data(nav);
    const index = LIST.indexOf(val);

    if (LIST.length === 0) {
      items.removeClass('selected');
      items.first().addClass('selected');
    } else {
      if (index === -1) {
        item.removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        item.addClass('selected');
      }
    }
  });
  
  updateResults();
}

function updateResults() {
  const results = $('.results .result');

  $.each(results, (i, el) => {
    const $el = $(el);

    const series = $el.data('series');
    const body = $el.data('body');
    const style = $el.data('style');

    const seriesIndex = SERIES.indexOf(series);
    const bodyIndex = BODY.indexOf(body);
    const styleIndex = STYLE.indexOf(style);
    
    let enabled = true;
    
    if (SERIES.length == 0) {
      if (BODY.length == 0) {
        if (styleIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else if (STYLE.length == 0) {
        if (bodyIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (bodyIndex == -1 || styleIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      }
    } else if (BODY.length == 0) {
      if (SERIES.length == 0) {
        if (styleIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else if (STYLE.length == 0) {
        if (seriesIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (seriesIndex == -1 || styleIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      }
    } else if (STYLE.length == 0) {
      if (SERIES.length == 0) {
        if (bodyIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else if (BODY.length == 0) {
        if (seriesIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (seriesIndex == -1 || bodyIndex == -1) {
          enabled = false;
        } else {
          enabled = true;
        }
      }
    } else { 
      if (seriesIndex == -1 || bodyIndex == -1 || styleIndex == -1) {
        enabled = false;
      } else {
        enabled = true;
      }
    }
    
    if (SERIES.length == 0 && BODY.length == 0 && STYLE.length == 0) {
      enabled = true;
    }

    if (!enabled) {
      $el.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $el.removeClass('disabled');
    }

  });
  
}
```

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
}

.result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="series-nav">
  <li data-series="all" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-series="Series 1">Series 1</li>
  <li data-series="Series 2">Series 2</li>
  <li data-series="Series 3">Series 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="body-nav">
  <li data-body="all" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-body="Body 1">Body 1</li>
  <li data-body="Body 2">Body 2</li>
  <li data-body="Body 3">Body 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="style-nav">
  <li data-style="all" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-style="Style 1">Style 1</li>
  <li data-style="Style 2">Style 2</li>
  <li data-style="Style 3">Style 3</li>
</ul>


<div class="results">
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 1" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 1">Result 1</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 1" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 1">Result 2</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 2" data-body="Body 2" data-style="Style 2">Result 3</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 2" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 2">Result 4</div>
  <div class="result" data-series="Series 3" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 1">Result 5</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 3" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 1">Result 6</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 3" data-body="Body 2" data-style="Style 2">Result 7</div>
   <div class="result" data-series="Series 2" data-body="Body 1" data-style="Style 3">Result 8</div>
</div>
```

So, I have 3 separate menus.

They all default to "All" if nothing is selected from that particular menu. The menu items are filters and you can select any number of filters from each menu. As the filters are clicked this builds 3 arrays with the selected items(see further below). The filters in each menu are linked or inclusive to the other menus, so a result must satisfy all selected filters otherwise it gets disabled class.

I have successfully written JS to handle the behaviour of each menu so the selected menu items/filters are highlighted using a css class. So thats all good.

The issue I'm having is when I try to filter the results.

These get populated with the values from the menu filters as they are clicked and if a filter is clicked twice the item is removed from the array.

As these arrays change I'm calling a function to update the results.

So the above update function is only working when all arrays have items. So I started adding further logic to the above conditionals to start checking if each of the arrays had items and if they didn't then ignore them and just filter based on the others. Obviously this then leads to having further logic to check if 2 of the 3 arrays are empty, etc etc. I feel like there must be a better way to do it without having dozens of nested if else statements. Maybe I need to approach from a completely different way.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I add my solution, I have to say thanks to *@ffriend* and his function to find out all combinations in two or more arrays (give to him +1 for this ;)): [Finding All Combinations (Cartesian product) of JavaScript array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-cartesian-product-of-javascript-array-values/4331218#4331218)

This function is very usefull and I used in my solution.

This is a different approch to your problem, so I had to change your HTML & your jQuery, of course.

First of all, the **HTML**. 
To create the same filter system as yours, I decided to used only classes without any particular attribute:

```
<div class="results">
   <div class="Series-1 Body-1 Style-1">Result 1</div>
   <div class="Series-1 Body-1 Style-1">Result 2</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-2 Style-2">Result 3</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-1 Style-2">Result 4</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-1 Style-1">Result 5</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-1 Style-1">Result 6</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-2 Style-2">Result 7</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-1 Style-3">Result 8</div>
</div>
```

...and I created a relation with all navs list (using also the *dot*)

```
<ul class="nav" data-obj="series">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-1">Series 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-2">Series 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-3">Series 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav" data-obj="body">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-1">Body 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-2">Body 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-3">Body 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav" data-obj="style">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-1">Style 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-2">Style 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-3">Style 3</li>
</ul>
```

In your CSS I removed only the `.disabled` class 'cause I used jQuery to do that.

Now the javascript. I have commented on the parts that I considered important to try to clarify all the steps:

```
/* I created one js object instead of 3 arrays, 'cause it is more simple to handle after in one general function */
var results = {
  series:[],
  body:[],
  style:[]
};

/* put the results containet in a variable */
var container=$(".results");

$(".nav li").on('click', function(){
  /*this is the general function that works for all your clicks */  

  /*set a few of variables */
  var $this=$(this);
  var parent=$this.parent();
  var parentObj=$this.parent().data("obj");
  var myClass=$this.data("el");
  var control=[]; /*this is an empty array that will set with your different classes*/

  if(myClass==="*") {
    /*click on first li*/
    if (!$this.hasClass("selected")) {
        /*do something if it didin't have the selected class*/
      $("li", parent).removeClass("selected"); /*remove selected classes from all li in my parent ul*/
      $this.addClass("selected");
      results[parentObj]=[];/* empty my associative object: series, body or style */
    }
  } else {
    /*click on the others li*/
    $("li[data-el='*']", parent).removeClass("selected"); 

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
        /*click on li with selected class */
      $this.removeClass("selected");

      results[parentObj]=$.grep(results[parentObj], function(value) {
        return value != myClass; /* I used $.grep() to filter the contents of my object. This function remove a class that I previous added (remember that <li> was selected so this class is still in this obj) */
      });
    } else {
      $this.addClass("selected");
      results[parentObj].push(myClass) /* add a class on associative object */
    }
  }
 /* Here I use a EC6 technique to loop through my object => https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/*/
  var entries = Object.entries(results);

  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    if (value.length>0)
        /* add ONLY array with classes in it */
      control.push(value);
    else
    /* Here I know that if the array is empty all my child li have no selected class, so I can add "selected" class to the first li (i.e. <li> with data-el='*' as attribute)*/
      $(".nav[data-obj='"+key+"'] li[data-el='*']").addClass("selected");
  }


  /* Set all div in results to opacity:.5*/
  $(".results > div").css({"opacity":".5"});

  if(control.length>0){
    var c=allPossibleCases(control).toString(); /* use that function to find all combinations in control (that it is an array without empty associative objects. I transform it in string to use it as group classes to remove the opacity rule */
    $(c, container).removeAttr("style"); /* remove the opacity:.5 to all group class that I found in control array*/
  } else {
    $(".results > div").removeAttr("style"); /*if control is empty I set the initial state removing the opacity */
  }
});

function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
    for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[0][j] + allCasesOfRest[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

That's it. All the code at work:

```js
var results = {
  series:[],
  body:[],
  style:[]
};

var container=$(".results");

$(".nav li").on('click', function(){
  var $this=$(this);
  var parent=$this.parent();
  var parentObj=$this.parent().data("obj");
  var myClass=$this.data("el");
  var control=[];

  if(myClass==="*") {
    if (!$this.hasClass("selected")) {
      $("li", parent).removeClass("selected");
      $this.addClass("selected");
      results[parentObj]=[];
    }
  } else {
    $("li[data-el='*']", parent).removeClass("selected");

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
      $this.removeClass("selected");

      results[parentObj]=$.grep(results[parentObj], function(value) {
        return value != myClass;
      });
    } else {
      $this.addClass("selected");
      results[parentObj].push(myClass)
    }
  }

  var entries = Object.entries(results);

  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    if (value.length>0)
      control.push(value);
    else
      $(".nav[data-obj='"+key+"'] li[data-el='*']").addClass("selected");
  }

  $(".results > div").css({"opacity":".5"});

  if(control.length>0){
    var c=allPossibleCases(control).toString();
    $(c, container).removeAttr("style");
  } else {
    $(".results > div").removeAttr("style");
  }
});

function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1));
    for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[0][j] + allCasesOfRest[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
}

.results > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav" data-obj="series">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-1">Series 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-2">Series 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Series-3">Series 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav" data-obj="body">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-1">Body 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-2">Body 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Body-3">Body 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav" data-obj="style">
  <li data-el="*" class="selected">All</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-1">Style 1</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-2">Style 2</li>
  <li data-el=".Style-3">Style 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="results">
   <div class="Series-1 Body-1 Style-1">Result 1</div>
   <div class="Series-1 Body-1 Style-1">Result 2</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-2 Style-2">Result 3</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-1 Style-2">Result 4</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-1 Style-1">Result 5</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-1 Style-1">Result 6</div>
   <div class="Series-3 Body-2 Style-2">Result 7</div>
   <div class="Series-2 Body-1 Style-3">Result 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to take a proper look at this but just want to say thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: As I told you, your question was really interesting. Sorry for the late reply, but it wasn't trivial at least for me ;-)