# How to create matrix table using json array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, matrix

I need to create one matrix table of each combination by comparing the two array object using Angular. I am explaining my code below.

```
ColumnNames= ["Colour", "Size"];
configArr={
  "Colour":["Black", "Red", "Blue","Grey"],
  "size": ["XS","S","XL","XXL","M"]
}
```

Here I have two array. My first array `ColumnNames` values will be the table column header and accordingly I need to create the matrix like below.

> Expected output::

```
Colour        Size

 Black          XS
 Black           S
 Black          XL
 Black         XXL
 Black          M
 Red           XS
 Red            S
 Red           XL
 Red           XXL
 Red            M

.................
................
................
```

Like the above format I need to display the data into angular table. I need only create the matrix dynamically.

Comment: Do you want this as an `html` table?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis: yes, first the matrix need to be formed and then I can bind that array inside one table.

Comment: Another question, do you only want to show the `ColumnNames` that you have defined, even if `configArr` has more properties? Example: `configArr` has `Colour`, `Size`, `Price`. `ColumnNames` only has `Colour` and `Size` -> so you only want to show `Colour` and `Size`, correct?

Comment: There may be more key values in future.

Comment: I understand that, I'm asking something else. I mean do you only want to show `ColumnNames` even if `configArr` has more key values? See my example please.

Comment: Only `configArr`  values will ob also ok inside the table.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution that works with any `configArr`, as long as all keys in that object are `string[]`. Inspired by [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52119/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-an-array-of-arrays-or-strings).

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";

  // Comment in/out properties here to see how the table changes
  configArr = {
    Colour: ["Black", "Red", "Blue", "Grey"],
    Size: ["XS", "S", "XL", "XXL", "M"],
    //Price: ["$5", "$10", "$15"],
    //Brand: ["B1", "B2", "B3"]
  };

  // This will be an [] of objects with the same properties as configArr
  matrix;

  allPossibleCases(arr) {
    // Taken almost exactly from the linked code review stack exchange link
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const configKeys = Object.keys(this.configArr);
    const arrOfarrs = configKeys.map(k => this.configArr[k]);
    const result = this.allPossibleCases(arrOfarrs);
    this.matrix = result.map(r => {
      const props = r.split(' ');
      let obj = {};
      for(let i=0;i<props.length;i++) {
        obj[configKeys[i]] = props[i]
      }
      return obj;
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let kv of configArr | keyvalue">{{ kv.key }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let elem of matrix">
      <td *ngFor="let kv of elem | keyvalue">{{ kv.value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acdzdj).

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-cartesian-product-of-javascript-array-values) for the algorithm behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
configArr.Colour.forEach((color) => {
  configArr.size.forEach((size) =>{
    console.log(color ,"  ", size); // Change this according to your table
  })
})
```

Comment: It should be map with `ColumnNames` values because there may be more values in future so it need to be dynamic. means the  values of  `ColumnNames` array will be the key name of `configArr`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let heading of ColumnNames"> {{heading}} </th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let color of configArr.Colour">
        <tr *ngFor="let size of configArr.size">
            <td>{{color}}</td>
            <td>{{size}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zajwc9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: No, it did not map with `ColumnNames` array. Tomorrow there may be some new value.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more "did not map with ColumnNames array"

Comment: Ok, Here each value of `ColumnNames` array are the keys for `configArr` json object. so if I will add `subject` to `ColumnNames` and `configArr={
  "Colour":["Black", "Red", "Blue","Grey"],
  "size": ["XS","S","XL","XXL","M"],
"subject": ["Math","History"]
}` then at this time what will happen.